# P Pr Pre Pref Prefi Prefix Prefixe Prefixes

Tags: code-golf, array

Given some finite list, return a list of all its prefixes, including an empty list, in ascending order of their length.

(Basically implementing the Haskell function [`inits`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:inits).)

#### Details

- The input list contains numbers (or another type if more convenient).
- The output must be a *list of lists*.
- The submission can, but does not have to be a function, any [default I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) can be used.
- There is a [CW answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177147/24877) for all [trivial solutions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11211/should-we-combine-answers-where-the-same-code-works-in-many-different-languages/11218#11218).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

#### Example

```
[] -> [[]]
[42] -> [[],[42]]
[1,2,3,4] -> [[], [1], [1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]]
[4,3,2,1] -> [[], [4], [4,3], [4,3,2], [4,3,2,1]]
```

Comment: If a language does not define any types except for characters, can I take input as a string and separate the input by newlines, in the case of a full program?

Comment: @NieDzejkob I'm not sure what consensus there is for this case, but the Brainfuck answer seems to do something like that.

Comment: Can we expect the list to be null-terminated?

Comment: It's especially common in C/C++, main use being strings.

Comment: @Rogem If it is that common I think allowing it is reasonable.

Answer (score 19):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 20 bytes

Edit: Yet a byte shorter with a completely different scan.

An anonymous function slightly beating the trivial import.

```hs
scanr(\_->init)=<<id
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcqxCsIwEADQvd/hkEIasHYqTRcnt4KLkAY50iQ9TE9JIv69sbi86a2QHjaEsgGSRMo2gsmHNwUkm8QGL5bW50c4waKFpe@vOSL5ZlSX/XobdV2L/62cnEsyQJHN92ZEwlzLYcClFKUr1bU7R97yE@/017gAPpXmdp6mHw)

- Uses `=<<` for the abbreviation `(scanr(\_->init)=<<id) l = scanr(\_->init) l l`.
- Scans a list `l` from right to left, collecting intermediate results with the function `\_->init`.
- That function ignores the elements scanned through (they're only used to get the right total length for the collected results), so really iterates applying `init` to the initial value of the scan, which is also `l`.

Answer (score 16):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>21</s> 12 bytes

*-9 bytes thanks to Arnauld suggesting the separator `ÿ` instead of newlines*

```
-[[<]>[.>],]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fNzraJtYuWs8uVif2//@AotS0zIrUYgA)

Takes bytes through STDIN with no null bytes and prints a series of prefixes separated by the `ÿ` character with a leading `ÿ` character. For example, for the input `Prefixes`, the output is `ÿÿPÿPrÿPreÿPrefÿPrefiÿPrefixÿPrefixeÿPrefixes`.

For readability, [here's a version with newlines instead](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGw6io21i7aL17GJ1Yv//DyhKTcusSC0GAA).

## Explanation:

```
-              Create a ÿ character in cell 0
 [        ,]   While input, starting with the ÿ
  [<]>           Go to the start of the string
      [.>]       Print the string
          ,      Append the input to the end of the string
```

Comment: This only works on BF implementations with 8-bit, unsigned, wrapping cells.

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript (ES6), 33 bytes

```javascript
a=>[b=[],...a.map(n=>b=[...b,n])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bco7DoAgEEXR3pVAMk4i0g4bIVOM32gQiBq3j9TG8p13d3nkGs8t321M01wWKkLOD@QZEFHwkKwiuQp1DhBZcxlTvFKYMaRVLcqz1s2HrPnBDgz0YP/y6ga6@pQX)

#### How?

```
+--- a = input array
|
|       +--- initialize b to an empty array and include it as the first entry
|       |    of the output (whatever the input is)
|       |
|       |          +--- for each value n in a[]:
|       |          |
|       |          |        +--- append n to b[] and include this new array in
|       |          |        |    the final output
|       |          |        |
a => [b = [], ...a.map(n => b = [...b, n])]
               |                  |
               +---------+--------+
                         |
      spread syntax: expands all elements of
      the child array within the parent array
```

Comment: wow, that's a whole new level of code explanation, awesome job :O

Comment: @BrianH. Thank you! Simple tasks are good opportunities to write detailed explanations that can't be brought up in denser code.

Comment: Did you make it by hand? or did you get help from any weird software i've never heard about?

Comment: Just Notepad++ with some [_column mode editing_](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html).

Answer (score 10):

## CW for all [trivial entries](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11211/should-we-combine-answers-where-the-same-code-works-in-many-different-languages/11218#11218)

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 19 bytes

Haskell version works in Clean too.

```
import StdLib
inits
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMUnM@l/cEkikGOrkJmXWVKsEG2oo2Cko2Cso2Cio2Cqo2AW@/9fclpOYnrxf11Pn/8ulXmJuZnJEA7EAAA)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 22 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
inits
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn//39mbkF@UYmCS2JJop5PZnEJV25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQmZeZkmxQrShnp5p7H8A)

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 6 bytes

```hs
prefix
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/3163oCg1LbNCI1In2lDHSMdYx0THNFZTp7wosyQ1J08jUlPH0NbA2tDWUO//fwA)

Comment: So torn - to upvote or not. On the one hand, I appreciate all the built-in solutions in one place. On the other, I really dislike builtins because they're so basic...

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ṭṖƤ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzrUPd047tuT/4fZHTWsUjk56uHMGiBH5/390rI5CtIkRiDTUUTDSUTDWUTCJBQA)

#### How it works

```
ṭṖƤ  Main link. Argument: A

  Ƥ  Map the link to the left over all non-empty(!) prefixes of A.
 Ṗ       Pop; remove the last element.
ṭ    Tack; append A to the resulting list.
```

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>40</s> 39 bytes

```r
function(L)lapply(0:length(L),head,x=L)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T8NHMyexoCCnUsPAKic1L70kAyiik5GamKJTYeuj@T9NIyezuERDU5MLyjIxQrANdYx0jHVMNDX/AwA)

*-1 byte thanks to [digEmAll](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41725/digemall)*

The output of R's `list` type is a bit weird; it uses sequential indexing, so for instance, the output for

`list(1,2)` is

```r
[[1]]                     # first list element
list()

[[2]]                     # second list element
[[2]][[1]]                # first element of second list element
[1] 1


[[3]]                     # third list element
[[3]][[1]]                # first element of third list element
[1] 1

[[3]][[2]]                # etc.
[1] 2
```

[Taking input as a vector instead](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T8NHMyexoCCnUsPAKic1L70kAyiik5GamKJTYeuj@T9NI680N7UoM1nDQFOTK00jWcPECMow1DHSMdYx0dT8DwA) gives a neater output format, although then the inputs are not technically `list`s.

Comment: [39 using lapply](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T8NHMyexoCCnUsPAKic1L70kAyiik5GamKJTYeuj@T9NIyezuERDU5MLyjIxQrANdYx0jHVMNDX/AwA "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 bytes

```
²£¯Y
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=sqOvWQ==&input=WzEsMiwzLDRdCi1R)

Explanation:

```
²       :Add an arbitrary extra item to the end of the array
 £      :For each item in the new array:
  ¯Y    : Get an array of the items that are before it
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 32 bytes

```python
f=lambda l:(l and f(l[:-1]))+[l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIcdKI0chMS9FIU0jJ9pK1zBWU1M7Oif2f0FRZl4JUDA6VpMLzjYxQuYZ6hjpGOuYxGr@BwA)

Comment: Also works in Python 3

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 13 bytes

```
{(),|[\,] @_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WkNTpyY6RidWwSG@9n9xYqWCUrVeemZxSa2CrZ1CtUKahkq8JlhAoVZJIS2/SAGoQcHESM8HKKSjoGGoo2Cko2AMFAIKa5iAmUABQ03r/wA)

To explain:

In Perl 6 you can wrap an operator in square brackets as an alternate way to write a list reduction.  `[+] @array` returns the sum of the elements in `@array`, `[*] @array` returns the product, etc.  You can also precede the operator with a backslash to make a "triangular" reduction, which some languages call "scan."  So `[\+] @array` returns a list consisting of the first element of `@array`, then the sum of the first two elements, then the sum of the first three elements, etc.

Here `[\,] @_` is a triangular reduction over the input array `@_` using the list construction operator `,`.  So it evaluates to a lists of lists: the first element of `@_`, the first two elements of `@_`, etc.  That's almost what's needed, but the problem calls for a single empty list first.  So the first element of the return list is a literal empty list `(),`, then the reduction over the input list is flattened into the rest of the return list with `|`.

Comment: O_o what is even happening here

Comment: @ASCII-only [triangular reduction](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#index-entry-%5B%5C%5D_%28triangular_reduction_metaoperators%29)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 36 bytes

```javascript
a=>[...a,0].map((x,y)=>a.slice(0,y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclLCoAgEADQ64wwDfbZ6kWkxWAahqlkRJ3eXD7ewQ9Xe4VyDylvrnnVWGlDRIxypZMLwIufUJqpxmAdyC7RbE41R0cx7@DBLDjjhOPa5wc)

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>22</s> 21 bytes

<sup>*-1 byte thanks to [Misha Lavrov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/74672)!*</sup>

```
{}~FoldList@Append~#&
```

Pure function. Takes a list as input and returns a list of lists as output. I believe this is the shortest possible solution.

Comment: We can write the same solution more compactly as `{}~FoldList@Append~#&`.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks! I didn't think to use the curried 1+2-argument form like that.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
Θḣ
```

Gets all the `ḣ`eads and then prepends `Θ` (in this case `[]`):

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9yMhzsW////P9pQx0jHWMckFgA)

<sup>(needs type annotation for empty list: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9yMhzsW////PzrWyscPAA))</sup>

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 5 bytes

```
a:,<\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WSiHRSscm5n9qcka@QpqCekFRalpmRWqxOhdUxFDBVMHsPwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 65 bytes

```powershell
param($a)'';$x=,0*($y=$a.count);0..--$y|%{$x[$_]=@($a[0..$_])};$x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRU13dWqXCVsdAS0Ol0lYlUS85vzSvRNPaQE9PV1elska1WqUiWiU@1tYBqDgaKApka9YCtfz//99Bw1DHSMdYx0QTAA)

PowerShell *helpfully* unrolls lists-of-lists when the default `Write-Output` happens at program completion, so you get one item per line. Tack on a [`-join','`](https://tio.run/##FYttC0AwFEb/zNU23S1v37TyPyQtKYRpCOG3X/Pt6ZzzLPZo3dq140i0GGcmDkYwlsOpMQo5XBqMauw@byKPlJISrie44SyhrnTh49JTv8XrL7@p5WD7mSF7iajgMSaYYiY@) to see the list-of-lists better, by converting the inner lists into strings.

(Ab)uses the fact that attempting to output an empty array (e.g., `@()`) results in no output, so an empty array input just has `''` as the output, since the `$a[0..$_]` will result in nothing. It will also throw out some [spectacular error messages.](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRU13dWqXCVsdAS0Ol0lYlUS85vzSvRNPaQE9PV1elska1WqUiWiU@1tYBqDgaKApka9YCtfz//99BQxMA)

Comment: [Wrapping it in parens instead of assigning it saves 20 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRU13d2kBPD8jSS84vzSvRNdSsUa3WcAAKRAPFVeJjNTVr////76BhomNkoGOmY6kJAA). Unless you don't think that counts as returning a list of lists. I've always been fuzzy on that distinction.

Comment: @veskah Yeah, that's almost what I had before my edit to this version. The problem with your solution or my earlier solution -- it doesn't return a list-of-lists. [TIO1](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmfVpqXXJKZn6eQpqFZ/b8gsSgxV0MlUVNd3dpATw/I0kvOL80r0TXUrFGt1nAACkQDxVXiYzU1a//XcmmkKagkFqUXRxvEghSoxOtm5Wfmqeuo1/7/76BhomNkoGOmY6kJAA "PowerShell – Try It Online") vs [TIO2](https://tio.run/##FYvRCoMgFEDf9xU93KF3qMgYgxFC/yERErk1SsOKFc1vd@7tcDhn8p8uzK9uGJJdXbv03hWW4pEmE8xIwSAhJWyKyQuFXYERrV/dgqUUgnPYv@cDNg1Nraoc62wzY8xLiidqCzDhOWtZ4z9s@Nv3jjASU6rojV0lu7MH/gA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
1_',\0,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NyjBeXSfGQOd/iVW1SnRlXZFVmkKFdUJ@trVGQlpiZo51hXWldZFmbC1XSbSigbWOokEskKVjYmStAeKaGGmC@IYKRgrGCiYQMUNrINcaLGQNldCM/Q8A)

Comment: This is some kind of voodoo. `,\(,()),` in K4. Joining enlisted null along enlisted input? howsitwork?

Comment: @streetster `()` is an empty list. `(,()),x` prepends it to `x`. finally `,\ ` does a concat-scan. the `x` is omitted to form a composition. note that the trailing `,` is dyadic, so it's "concat", not "enlist".

Comment: @streetster in k4 it can be a byte shorter: `1_',\0,` but my parser isn't smart enough to handle this...

Answer (score 3):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 39 bytes

```lisp
(defun f(l)`(,@(if l(f(butlast l))),l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dck7CsAgEAXAq7wub8Emvz5HyccsCItI1PNvbKaZx1It7oyv9gylyclwMCmMyrs3u2qDiUgYOMuXcgMVE2csWLFhH@k/)

#### Explanation

```lisp
(defun f(l)                           )  ; Define a function f
           `(                        )   ; With the list (essentially capable of interpolation), containing:
             ,@                          ;     The value of, flattened to one level
               (if l              )      ;         If l is not the empty list (which is the representation of nil, i.e. the only falsy value)
                    (f(butlast l))       ;         Recurse with all of l but the tail
                                   ,l    ;     The value of l
```

Answer (score 3):

### F#, 53 bytes

I've actually got two pretty similar answers for this, both the same length. They both take a generic sequence `s` as a parameter.

First solution:

```
let i s=Seq.init(Seq.length s+1)(fun n->Seq.take n s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1BC4JAFITv/oqHEChhZHUzFzx0DzqKh0VWe7i9rd1XIPTfN9cinNPMNzDTuaw1VnmvFQOCKy/qsUFCToLRinq@glvnadI9CSgTAbMcFBC41NfHE7EdzwaJRROFkZtEAmn7F5QRTAqsNVqrltHQDwbVh2Jf7Iq8@ZO3AFyG@ctU1soxmvndTj8dQbyq4sXot9z6Dw)

`Seq.take` takes the first `n` elements of the sequence. `Seq.init` creates a new sequence with a count (in this case) of the length of sequence `s` plus 1, and for each element in the sequence takes the first `n` elements in `s`.

Second solution:

```
let i s=Seq.map(fun n->Seq.take n s){0..Seq.length s}
```

Similar to before, except it creates a sequence from 0 to the length of `s`. Then takes that number of elements from `s`.

[Try this online too!](https://tio.run/##TY09C4MwFEV3f8VDKLSDwX5s1oBD90JHcQgSbWh80Ze0IG1/e2psKd7tnAv3NjapDUnvtXSgwOYXObBO9OvmjoAJD@jETQKC3TxTxoLQElt3Bfv25fGEjsazUeh4FYWRTigEQe0D8gimBFcbrWXtlMGfDCkP2T7bZdvqb14c1BLmc1MQiTGafU/TT4MQr4p4MfotU/8B)

Comment: `fun s->Seq.map(fun n->Seq.take n s){0..Seq.length s}`  saves 1 byte

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```ruby
->a{[a*i=0]+a.map{a[0,i+=1]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xOjpRK9PWIFY7US83saA6MdpAJ1Pb1jC2tvZ/gUKanoZCdKwCFGgq2NoqREfHxnJBZUyMYlFldEBCcGlDHSMdYx2TWIQ0UAxM6BhBKR1jOAOoEGEwkGukY4ii0wRMQDSA5eEMoMLY/wA)

Explanation:

```ruby
->a{             # take array input a
  [a*i=0]+       # set i to 0 and add whatever comes next to [[]] (a*0 == [])
  a.map{         # for every element in a (basically do a.length times)
    a[0,i+=1]  # increment i and return the first i-1 elements of a to map
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## MATL, <s>15</s> 12 bytes

*3 bytes saved thanks to @Giuseppe*

```
vin:"G@:)]Xh
```

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=vin%3A%22G%40%3A%29%5DXh&inputs=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D&version=20.10.0).

Due to the way that MATL displays the output, you can't explicitly see the empty array in the cell array. [Here](https://matl.suever.net/?code=vin%3A%22G%40%3A%29%5DXh%26D&inputs=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D&version=20.10.0) is a version that shows the output a little more explicitly.

**Explanation**

```
v       # Vertically concatenate the (empty) stack to create the array []
i       # Explicitly grab the input
n       # Compute the number of elements in the input (N)
:       # Create an array from [1, ..., N]
"       # Loop through this array
  G     # For each of these numbers, M
  @:    # Create an array from [1, ..., M]
  )     # Use this to index into the initial array
]       # End of the for loop
Xh      # Concatenate the entire stack into a cell array
```

Comment: use `v` instead of `[]`. And doesn't `:` use `1` as the default first argument? So this could be `vin:"G@:)]Xh` for 12 bytes.

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks! My MATL is a little rusty it seems :(

Answer (score 3):

## [SWI PROLOG](http://www.swi-prolog.org) 22 bytes

`i(X,Y):-append(X,_,Y).`

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
{∧Ė|a₀}ᶠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v/pRx/Ij02oSHzU11D7ctuD//2hDHSMdYx2T2P9RAA)

#### Explanation

```
{     }ᶠ    Find all:
 ∧Ė          The empty list
   |         Or
    a₀       A prefix of the input
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 6 bytes

```
Ｅθ…θκθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUCjUEfBuTI5J9U5Ix/MydbU1LTmgsgXalr//x8drWSopKOgZAQijEGEiVJs7H/dshwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 θ      Input array
Ｅ       Map over elements
   θ    Input array
  …     Moulded to length
    κ   Current loop index
        Implicitly print each array double-spaced
     θ  Input array
        Implicitly print
```

It's possible at a cost of 1 byte to ask Charcoal to print an `n+1`-element array which includes the input as its last element, but the output is the same, although the cursor position would be different if you then went on to print something else.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
η¯š
```

Explanation:

```
η    Prefixes
  š  Prepend
 ¯   Global array (empty by default)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3PZD648u/P8/2sQoFgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [RAD](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/rad), 7 bytes

```
(⊂⍬),,\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pM@f9f41FX06PeNZo6OjH///83VDBSMFYwAQA)

This also works in Dyalog APL as a function.

### How?

This works the same for both APL and RAD, given their close relation.

- `(⊂⍬)` the empty array
- `,` prepended to
- `,\` the prefixes (which exclude the empty array.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 37 bytes

```
{x->(0..x.size()).collect{x[0..<it]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/F9iG22oY6RjrGMSy1Vp@7@6QtdOw0BPr0KvOLMqVUNTUy85PycnNbmkuiIaKGyTWRJbW/u/oCgzryQnT6FSo0TzPwA)

Comment: `{it.inits().reverse()}` will work once we get groovy 2.5 on TIO

Answer (score 2):

## [Java 8+](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>86</s> 77 bytes

<sup>-9 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) (getting rid of the import)!</sup>

```java
x->java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0,x.size()+1).mapToObj(t->x.subList(0,t))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDRSsMwFH3vV1wGQqJpcHNvnQUfFATFh/kmIlmX1dQ2CUk6OmXfXm/XDp2bebnJyT3n3HMLsRaxsVIXy49WVda4AAVivA6q5OdJdIStap0FZfTJTx@cFBWf70oSRbZelCqDrBTew6NQGr6iCGCAfRABy92gOHtQPszudZC5dCnrRQ7BNAWlVfBw3TZxeuSLbT2LO6FzSS5Zw736lIRejCmvhH02T4uChDhFvF500tgTKG0BT4KTHQ23NmoJFU5OUFnp/OUVhMs9xSAdJzeEJvvbdPJzH7MJu2LTX5/4nLDxDthGp32wbUjKOW/8297lYAfQYHy4cU5sPBd@F6Lr7Z3mGx9kxU0duMV5w4qMzjzEKYwYElm/Pi6sLTfIogPrD8pXxt2K7J3gkk8Ldmr0H8tSkyHltv0G)

### Alternative, 65 bytes

The following will print the results to *stdout* (due to [Olivier Grégoire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16236/olivier-gr%C3%A9goire)):

```java
x->{for(int i=0;i<=x.size();)System.out.print(x.subList(0,i++));}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##dVDBTsMwDL33K6xJSClro23s1q0S4oQEpx0RQlmXVR5tUsXp1DH124s7OsEY5BLn@T0/v@zUXsW20ma3ee@wrKzzsGNM1h4LeZsEV9i2NplHa/pmUNXrAjPICkUEzwoNHIMAYIDJK8/XgzVUl9otnpD84tF4nWuXpoAGPcGya@L0uLVOoPGAy0mCi2UjCT@0CJNwdSCvS2lrLyvHDMGtet1PEpMIx@MwTNoOIGHXK@O9xQ2UvJVYedbmL6@gXE4hLwl8cssG52o@@66n0Sy6i@Y/mvycRdMT0AZ/@zBtiCalbOjt7HIRGhoODPfOqQNJRacYPffL6XfWrRjdEMQpjCIWDqTTr0mVZbrqtf9ICyOGbdvuEw)

Comment: You can golf it to 77 bytes by just using `java.util.stream.IntStream` directly and drop the import.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Oh thanks! I didn't even know that this was possible, that's certainly helpful (at least for golfing purposes).

Comment: `x->{for(int i=0;i<=x.size();)System.out.println(x.subList(0,i++));}` ([67 bytes](https://tio.run/##dVDBbsIwDL33KyxO7SgRME5LQZp2mrSdOE7TFEqo3LVJFaeoDPHtndsVbQiWi5337Lz3kqu9mthKm3z72WJZWechZ0zUHgtxJ4MrbFeb1KM1N0nyTqtSrPsig6CqNwWmkBaKCF4VGjgGAcAAk1eey5M1VJfaJS9IPnk2XmfarVaABj3Bsm0mq@POuhCNB1xOJSbLRhB@6TCS0fpAXpfC1l5UjicKEzJZb7q3wmmM43EUyVMLfCQrX4nvLW6hZGchm0aTvb2DchlFbLTbySyLnLvF/LefxfP4Pl78Ifk6j2c9cApu6/DYEE8I0dDHWeUiODQcGh6dUwcSivog3eyP0o28o@ZhNLD9lwmVprrqlv7fGWye2m8)). This prints instead of using streams. Printing is usually the shortest way to output complex structures.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire: In that case you can probably get away with `System.out.print` since the output is still unambiguous.

Comment: @BMO Indeed, that would be possible!

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 bytes

```
Êò@¯Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//3DX4U0Oh9ZH/v8fbahjpGOsYxLLxaUbCAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 43 bytes

Take a list of non-null characters as input and returns all prefixes separated by newline. Requires double-infinite or wrapping tape.

```
,>-[+>,]<[-<]<<++++++++++[[<]>[.>]>[-<+>]<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fx043WttOJ9YmWtcm1sZGGw6io21i7aL17ICEro22XaxN7P//AUWpaZkVqcUA)

Comment: [Another answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177194/69850) outgolfed me by more than a half, because I didn't think about printing output *while* reading. Of course that method won't work with printing increasing suffixes.

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGw7s7HSi7XRibaJtYu2io3VttO2gbD27WLvY//8DilLTMitSiwE) with some rearranging

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, 24 bytes

```powershell
,@()
$args|%{,($x+=,$_)}
```

Explanation:

1. The trivial accumulator wrapped to array by unary `,`.
2. The script uses [splatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting). See parameter `@a`.

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

,@()
$args|%{,($x+=,$_)}

}

@(
    ,( @()        , @() )
    ,( @(42)      , @(@(),@(42)) )
    ,( @(1,2,3,4) , @(@(), @(1), @(1,2), @(1,2,3), @(1,2,3,4)) )
    ,( @(4,3,2,1) , @(@(), @(4), @(4,3), @(4,3,2), @(4,3,2,1)) )
) | % {
    $a,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f @a

    $false -notin $(
        $result -is [array]
        $result.Count -eq $expected.Count
        for($j=0; $j-lt$result.Count; $j++){
            "$($result[$j])" -eq "$($expected[$j])"
        }
    )

    # $result   # uncomment this line to display a result

}
```

Output:

```powershell
True
True
True
True
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 39 bytes

```cs
x=>x.Select((_,i)=>x.Take(i)).Append(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/LCsIwEEX3@YqQVYJjwepOW3ChoLir4KIUqXGqQY2SplqQfnuNL9TiZuCeucNhZN6WuarHhZaDyUgXBzTpao8DpW0I36C5DEOa0aAug7D0ItyjtJwvQYl7nqc75EoIb3g6oV7zUtR9QtxVnMQJtZjbnAZU44W@GLkS@snXCn5iz2@ADvjQhV6z5pgPHUcrZyPZ0WAqt/ycmofStZ5q8bAtjLI4Uxo5i1krskbpjTc9Ks0ZMMj4vSren7kv/7VK0WIJE8/ZJ1V9Aw)

Comment: You need to include the using `System.Linq;`  in your bytecount. And it seems some of your output logic is in your outputting of the arrays. Because empty array just returns empty array.

Comment: @LiefdeWen - my understanding is that since this interpreter includes a reference to `System.Linq`, I don't have to include this in the byte count. My submission would be considered a different language than say `.NET Core`. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/C%23-Interactive-Walkthrough - You mention printing which is a separate issue, I'd like to get clarity on this first.

Comment: With regards to printing, here is a version that basically dumps the result to the console - https://tio.run/##XY29CsIwGEX3PEXGBGKhtVt/wEHBTdCtFInxKwZrLEmqhdJnj2kV1I733Hs5wiyEkW7TKpFu16q9geanGlKpbM5@wbzMc1zhzHVZ3gV7qEFYQo5M0jEf@BWIpDRYNQ2oM@moSxDyr6IsSmzBWIMzrOCJPwz1CH9zP7C/GEczELKILVk8n3kWsdDTwdtQddfAxYU8uJ6UfvVW08m20/5FKjIiShM0uBc - not as pretty for sure! The question I have is when is it acceptable to use `Array` vs `IList` vs `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 2):

## [F# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), 45 bytes

```fs
fun x->List.mapi(fun i y->List.take i x)x@[x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWzc3Py/@fk1qikKZgq6DxP600T6FC184ns7hELzexIFMDJJCpUAkVKknMTgVyKzQrHKIrYv9rWltzcRUUZeaVpOUpKKk6KilopEXHamIImRhhETS0NrI2tjbBphwobmRtGKv5HwA)

I am not totally sure if this is valid, but it seems like it follows the same "anonymous lambda" syntax that I've seem used in several other languages.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>102</s> 97 bytes

Pretty long, as C quite obviously isn't well-suited to manipulating lists of lists. Dependent on certain behavior; running on some platforms requires changing `int` to `short` (for +2 bytes), due to `wchar_t` being UTF-16 rather than UTF-32. Should work on Linux as-is.

Takes in a pointer to the first element of the input array, the length of the array, and a pointer to the variable in which the pointer to output will be stored. Produces a list of lists such that the first integer in the linear array stores the number of sub-lists. Sub-lists start with the number of elements, and are stored in memory in a contiguous manner.

```c
p(r,e,f,i,x)int*e,**r,*x;{x=*r=malloc(4-++f*~f*2);*x++=f;for(i=0;i<f;x+=++i)wmemcpy(x+1,e,*x=i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFNbxMxEIbP2V9hGRX5YypICBzqWggBBy4VKrkl0Srd2JWjjbPybsVCtPz1MOM2kEY9eTzvzON3xtXlfVUdDo1I4MBDgF6G2CkHSiVQvdn3ViW7XdX1rhLTS629@uPVRBrVa2298bskgn1rwrU3vbZaB/lz67ZV80v0eoxM1dsgzXBoEnLLOrSdoAdquS9GGLBoVa21KUbNQ9cKPucS40xF8ZEcTdBaMmzIHW347Y5No4z1gi@6OYeAL5JKCGKwDNkgZHNNebNBDkr/ui7CRcuBWMCBa7HRY2szQZ7Cl1TFYRGxJFBJzPpwNL1EBRNDsZov7X6A4o7OyRSjiqIxTOAd0HV9coX38GEwxXYVopD7UfFq7XyIjs2@/piVn26@lN9vv93MxColnH1BtmkaVSbXQhmzzZ1nKL@ZmsXpVJ/xt0K8Z42QbBcZrTTrz7daPq41K2cLQeY8LCGPWsaPnF/h@NI8DXvENeJ19oLV6Ec@93Dr2oe6u2LU9v/nqf5oJjn3dMc9ns9M6z3L3b2Qq17IreknDn8B)

### Degolf

```c
p(r,e,f,i,x) int**r,*e,*x; // Function p(), where r is a pointer to the output variable,
                           // e is a pointer to the input location and f is the size of
                           // the input.
{ 
  x=*r=malloc(4-++f*~f*2); // Allocate 4*(x+1)*(x+2)/2+4 bytes of memory. 
                           // This is the exact amount of memory needed.
  *x++=f;                  // Store n+1 (number of sub-lists) in the first four bytes. 
  for(i=0;i<f;x+=++i)      // Iterate over [0, n]->i and 
                           // increment the pointer to x by i+1 every iteration.
    wmemcpy(x+1,e,*x=i);   // Set first element at location pointed to by x to i,
                           // then copy i of either 2 or 4 byte elements, depending on
                           // the system wchar implementation, to location pointed to
                           // by x+1.
}
```

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks, will edit it in later when I get back onto a PC.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 21 bytes

```scala
_.inits.toSeq.reverse
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYq9CgIxEAb7e4qvTCAE/KkEBXutLEWOeO7BStiLyXII4rPHqN3MMGUIMdTpeqdBcQwsoKeS3Ar2KeHVAXOIGDc40ePcX7Dd/ehvTWvvWViL16k1n2mmXKgCKbNoFDOaAxc1C4elw8phbW17v8127/oB)

Not quite a trivial answer, since I had to deal with the fact that the `inits` method returns an iterator in the reverse of the required order.

Comment: Not sure if this is valid since this is a function, not a lambda (and you're excluding the function declaration part). Hmmmmmm

Comment: @ASCII-only This is Scala's underscore shorthand syntax. It's basically a lambda. Compare to Haskell's sections. See also https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11223/untyped-functions-in-static-languages

Comment: Yes, but it can not be assigned to a variable (lambda function). On the other hand, [`{_.inits.toSeq.reverse}` can](https://tio.run/##JYoxC8IwFAb3/opvbCEUqk6Cg4uTTo4llFhf4Ul5icmzCKW/PbY43XFc6t3osn@8qFfcHAvoqyTPhHMImAtgchHD8fKRXtlL097p3XbWYOPfrcUpz13Nwppq9WutI00UEy0ZCJFFRymH8spJy8ZgZ7A3OFTVOm@tKpb8Aw).

Comment: @ASCII-only Nope, the braces are not needed (though you do need to use val instead of var for some reason): https://tio.run/##JYq9CgIxEAb7e4qvTCAE/KkEBXutLEWOeO7BStiLyXII4rPHqN3MMGUIMdTpeqdBcQwsoKeS3Ar2KeHVAXOIGDc40ePcX7Dd/ehvTWvvWViL16k1n2mmXKgCKbNoFDOaAxc1C4elw8phbW17v8127/oB

Comment: Oh wait, you can define functions like variables, nvm

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

That was my first succesfull golf! Thanks for being such a nice community!

```
)UŒ¹g£Xš
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fM/TopEM70w8tjji68P//aEMdIx3jWAA)

### Explanation:

```
)UŒ¹g£Xš
)        : Create an empty list
 U       : Save it to variable ˙X˙
  Œ      : Make the "substrings" of the implicit input
   ¹g£   : Take the first n elements of the result where n is the lenght of input
      Xš : Add the empty list to the beginning
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Swift](https://www.swift.org), <s>60</s> 54 bytes

```swift
let f={(i:[Int])in return[[]]+i.indices.map{i[...$0]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU1LCsIwEN3nFENxkWAMNmYl1L1nSGchmsCApiUdcVF69hgr@jbvC296UWRXyj0wxG6WdPTnxKgoQQ78zMl7xC0ZSje6hsk8LuNM3hiz2eOylDhkYKhjL6DCo/6ysz/VaqsP2v2LaqxuUSDMa/I5ztBBlKzWYMyUWDZ99bA7QS@zapRYyhs)

Defines a function that takes an array of ints and returns an Array of ArraySlices (i.e, they reference the same memory as the input array). To turn into real arrays, it's <s>67</s> 61 bytes.

```swift
let f={(i:[Int])in return[[]]+i.indices.map{Array(i[...$0])}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language), 7 bytes

```
ωωι0;↑←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y638//985/nOczsNrB@1TXzUNuH////RhjpGOsY6JrEA)

Woah ... never thought MY would actually come in handy.

### How?

`ωωι0;↑←`

- `ω` = `push(arg[0])`
- `ω` = `push(arg[0])`
- `ι` = `push([1 ... pop()])`
- `0` = `push(0)`
- `;` = `push(pop() + pop())`
- `↑` = does the prefixing work by vecifying in a stupid manner.
- `←` output

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 48 bytes

```cs
l=>new int[l.Count()+1].Select((_,n)=>l.Take(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY09C8IwFEX3/oqHS/JoDPg11WYpCoqbgkMtouFVgvEV2hQH8bfXLIIIdzqXe67txrZzw7pnu9ysuH9Qe7l6WjoORv2C/9IYqCEffG6YnhBJ6XXR9BwkppNK78mTDVKeFWNuvD5c7iQZcciSpGi4azzpY@sC7RyT7ELr@Ka3jWMpTiwU1DJqy@o1UTBVMFMwV7B449cbb0UpIIXf5UhBjMeIRSUQMRs@)

#### Explanation

```cs
l=>                                                // Function with list l as argument
   new int[l.Count()+1]                            // A new array (int is shortest type available) of length l + 1
                       .Select((_,n)=>l.Take(n))   // Where every element is mapped to the first n elements of the input list, where n is the index
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua 5.3, 92 bytes

```
function f(...)t=...if#t>0then return f({table.unpack(t,1,#t-1)},...)else return{...}end end
```

Keeps creating a copy of the array-like table with the element at the end removed and prepending it to the varargs until the length of the table is 0, then puts the varargs in a table. Relies on defining the variable `f` to allow recursion.

## Lua 5.1, 87 bytes

```
function f(...)t=...if#t>0 then return f({unpack(t,1,#t-1)},...)else return{...}end end
```

`unpack` is a global variable rather than a member of the `table` library. `0then` is syntactically invalid in Lua 5.1, but strangely not in Lua 5.3.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 23 bytes

```
a->[a[1..n]|n<-[0..#a]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYjBCoAgEAV/5WGXBJWsjuWPLHvYixGELNEl6N/Nugwzo3LuftOasaKKTyQUQyj8lMXTEEInzFVUj7sX@AQ993I1NV8Y5F6sdSDihnn8GB1Gh8lh/t@vbURmW18)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 16 bytes

```
{h@<a}M,1+#(h:a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@F/9vzrDwSax1lfHUFtZI8MqUfN/rYKvQjSXgkJ0LIgwMQJThgpGCsYKJrFcsf//6wYAAA)

#### Explanation

```
      M            Map
{h@<a}                 Function returning global variable h, cut at index a, and left part taken (0-indexed)
       ,               Range from 1 to
        1+#(   )           1 + the length of
            h:a                Assign global variable h to a, evaulating to the value of h (which is also the value of a - the first parameter to the function)
```

Comment: [Similar approach, 22](https://tio.run/##K8gs@F/9Pzo6NlZPozrDwUZbO7HW11UjwypRU/N/rYKvQjSXgkJ0LIgwMQJThgpGCsYKJrFcsf//6wYAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>34</s> 31 bytes

```ruby
->l{(0..l.size).map{|i|l[0,i]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cup1rDQE8vR684sypVUy83saC6JrMmJ9pAJzO2tvZ/dHSsTrSJEZAw1DHSMdYxAXGBtJGOYWysXmpicoZCSr5CTWZeQWlJDZeCQoFCWjSYE8uVmpfyHwA)

Thanks @ConorO'Brien!

Comment: You can golf this a bit like so: ``->l{(0..l.size).map{|i|l[0,i]}}``, using `[0,i]` for indexing instead of `.first i`

Comment: @ConorO'Brien: Thanks a lot! 1 fewer byte than Python now :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://github.com/factor/factor), 63 bytes

```
USE: fry [ [ dup '[ nip _ swap head ] map-index ] keep suffix ]
```

Keeps a copy of the input to tack on at the end, like C#.

Answer (score 1):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 18 bytes

```
00000000: 2511 00ff 1b1a ffa7 20fa cd03 802b 7730  %....... ....+w0
00000010: f076                                     .v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jcxPCkBAGIbxvVO8Gyul9xsxk1O4wvjzSSlFIZcfNA7gt3iWz@U4LrOGwE8NU4qAVIW04qHqLQzVo@tZwNG0sLYgkOYR3mQHk3iQ56G0Ff7I9xCaddDpHLYb)

Takes bytes through STDIN with no null bytes and prints a series of prefixes, each terminated by a null byte.

Source code:

```
    dec h
start:
    ld de, $ff00
.printloop:
    dec de
    ld a, (de)
    rst $38
    and a
    jr nz, .printloop
    call $8003
    dec hl
    ld (hl), a
    jr nc, start
    halt
```

Answer (score 1):

## [FALSE](http://strlen.com/false-language/), 57 bytes

```
1^[$~][\1+^]#%a:0[$a;1->~][0[$@$@>][\$a;\-ø,1+]#\%10,1+]#
```

[Try it online!](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/false-js.html) (you'll have to copy paste the code. Click "Show" and then run)

Like brainf*ck, FALSE only takes one char at a time as input, so this program splits a string into prefixes, separating them with a newline.

Explanation:

```
1^         {push 1 {counter) and first character onto stack}
[$~][      {while a character is input:}
  \1+^     {add 1 to the counter}
]#

%          {drop truth value from stack}
a:         {define the counter as the variable "a'}
0          {push 0 onto stack (loopvar)}
[$a;1->~][ {while loopvar is less than a-1:}

  0        {push 0 (loopvar2)}
  [$@$@>][ {while loopvar is greater than loopvar2}
    \$a;\- {a-loopvar2 (to get index of char to print)}
    ø,     {copy value at index to top of stack and print}
    1+     {increment loopvar2}
  ]#
  \%       {swap'n'drop (get rid of loopvar2)}
  10,      {print newline}
  1+       {increment loopvar}
]#
```

A FALSE expert could probably do this using no variables (pure stack) but since I only learnt this language yesterday I think this is alright.

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/create_explanation.py), <s>9</s> <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
hÅ_╡]x
```

-1 byte thanks to *@maxb*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/jcGv8o6kLYyv@/4821jG01DHQMTIy0jE3jAUA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7X6ik8KhtkoJS4f@Mw63xj6YujK34/z86livaxAhIGOoY6RjrmIC4QNpIxxDIMtYxtNQx0DEyMtIxN4wFAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
h        # Push the length of the (implicit) input-array, without popping the array
 Å       # Loop this length amount of times,
         # and do the following two commands each iteration:
  _      #  Duplicate the array at the top of the stack
   ╡     #  Remove the right-most item of the array
    ]    # After the loop, wrap everything on the stack in an array
     x   # Reverse it (and output implicitly)
```

Comment: `hÅ_╡]x` saves one byte. For doing test suites, just add one input per line, and the code will be executed separately for each input. Check my answer for an example. I should describe that feature better in the docs.

Comment: @maxb Thanks, that simplifies the test suite a lot. Need to remember that. And thanks for the golf!

Answer (score 1):

## [D](https://dlang.org), 49 bytes (11 imports, 38 expression)

```
import std;
alias prefixes = t=>iota(t.length+1).map!(i=>t.take(i));
```

[Try it online!](https://run.dlang.io/is/hKyGSq)

edit: Do I count the `alias prefixes =` part? You can use the lambda without it, but you have to add parens to disambiguate, so should I count it as 42?

edit: We now got `import std;` as a shortcut. That solves things!

Comment: I don't program in D, but I think you don't count the alias prefixes.  Python lambdas are very similar and they act in that way.

Comment: There is one problem though. I'm pretty sure you need to count the imports.

Comment: Wait, none of the others use standard library routines? edit: I feel it'd be kind of silly to make code size dependent on what standard definitions the language chooses to make available by default. That seems more of a judgment of a language's module system than its expressivity.

Comment: Though fair enough, the Java example seems to count module names. Bleh. edit: Though it seems pretty nonsensical to count the imports and not the alias, and in any case what about the `void main()`... seems like it'd just become a boilerplate size contest, rather than expression size.

Comment: You don't have to count the main function nor the stdio import (which is only used in the main function), but importing algorithm and range contributes to the score.

Comment: Alright.. feels like I'm mostly counting letters in names, but sure.
I think it seems so arbitrary because I'm basically discounting pieces in the middle of the code.

Comment: One would count this as if it was `import std.algorithm,std.range;t=>(t.length+1).iota.map!(i=>t.take(i))`

Comment: So, in response to my above comment: this would count as 70 bytes. (Note: a golf was applied changing two imports to a single import)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 7 bytes

```
hæ_ï<\]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/j8LL4w@ttYmL//4@O5Yo2MQIShjpGOsY6JiAukDbSMYz9DwA)

### Explanation

```
h         length of array/string without popping
 æ        start block of length 4
  _       duplicate TOS
   ï      index of current loop, or length of last loop
    <     slice list
     \    swap top elements
      ]   end array / wrap stack in array
```

Comment: Nice 7 byte alternative to [my 7-byter I found an hour ago](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177311/52210). :) Actually, I see I can golf mine to 6 bytes by changing `{` to `Å`. Thanks for the implicit golf. Now I just need to fix the test suite somehow..

Comment: You could save a byte for that one by replacing `{` with `Å` and removing the `}`. MathGolf has 1-byte literals for blocks of size up to 8 bytes.

Comment: Just edited my comment when I realized that. Just not sure how to fix the test suite..

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 21 bytes

```
#(reductions conj[]%)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gambit Scheme (gsi)](http://gambitscheme.org), <s>77</s> 72 bytes

```scm
(define(p z)(if(pair?(car z))(p(cons(reverse(cdr(reverse(car z))))z))z))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jczBCsIwEATQu1@xx8mhh8be/ZaYbu2CjcsmCPbnY6pCbyoMyyw8JseZF@4uYTlLqRUjT5IYSquDTNAgdkIM1n4HRbylDOM7W2bE0fb@Js6tr1SocSmPTk1SobaHq@TyuZs7fBWD/2168nSk4Y@xxjz1G6xP)

First time using Scheme. It's a function that takes a wrapped list (`(list (list 1 2 3 4))`) as an argument.

Comment: I think you might want to reverse that `if` test.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Yep. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 102

- Input is in Row 1
- A2: `COUNTA(1:1)`
- Output: `=ArrayFormula(IF(A2,{T(SEQUENCE(1,A2));IF(SEQUENCE(A2)>=SEQUENCE(1,A2),OFFSET(A1,,,,A2),)},`

### Output Formatted:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(
  A2,
  {
    T(SEQUENCE(1,A2));
    IF(
      SEQUENCE(A2)>=SEQUENCE(1,A2),
      OFFSET(A1,,,,A2),
    )
  },
))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 14 bytes

```
L*,¬b[€bFbUBpA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HS@fQmqToR01rktySQp0KHP@r5CTmJqUkKhjaRcdy@XMhcU2M0AQMFYwUjBVM0JUBxYwUDIGi/wE)

### How it works

```
L		; Lambda function. Takes A as argument
	*,	; Return the enire stack
		; E.g. A = [1 2 3 4]
	¬b[	; Scan pair;	STACK = [[1 [1 2] [[1 2] 3] [[[1 2] 3] 4]]]
	€bF	; Flatten each;	STACK = [[[1] [1 2] [1 2 3] [1 2 3 4]]]
	bU	; Splat;	STACK = [[1] [1 2] [1 2 3] [1 2 3 4]]
	Bp	; Pop each;	STACK = [[] [1] [1 2] [1 2 3]]
	A	; Push A;	STACK = [[] [1] [1 2] [1 2 3] [1 2 3 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
K¾p
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=K%C2%BEp&inputs=%5B4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D&header=&footer=)

Comment: [Unfortunately, the results have to contain the empty list.](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=K%C2%BEp&inputs=%5B4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D&header=&footer=)

Comment: I'm not happy that the 1 byte answer isn't valid either. But 3 bytes is the best I can think of

Comment: @lyxal oh i didn't  notice the empty list requirement before, but we have to accept our fate, whatever

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 26 bytes

```julia
~l=0:length(l).|>i->l[1:i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU7BCsIwDL33KwJeNsjEdjsNtrvfEHoQrFopVbYMPMh@vbZ1FJbDy8t7LyHPxdmL/ISwuuHUO@Pv/KhcffyOthkdyd7qwGbmGQYgcfZMGiHVAZoRiLQW1KlNKyImLToSFbbYRbs4QDIDqq1hW0hMpnORKJT7pS7DP5sDhcSkFlrcXhMwWA/5W5G@eU/Ws/PVyvVuroXx1/AD)

**alternative solution in Julia 1.6+, 26 bytes:**

`~l=first.([l],0:length(l))`
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU5BCsMgELz7ioVcFLahmtBDID301n5BPARqWovYEi3klK@naoOQPczOzswu@/paM/B5reCWGPD6RC6D1/VoJh/ojIb1s@SdUeti@yzWVFqFx85q9whPahlbg/bBQw@SXF2QCiFVBYczSKkUka3YtCJi0qLDUWCDbbSLA5JnQLE1bAqJyXQuEoF8v9Rm@GdzoJCYVESR8T1BAOMgf0vSN5/JuGAdXQLbzYxod19/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 6 bytes

```
_H,U#_
```

Anonymous function that takes an iterable and returns a list of iterables. (A full program would be the same number of bytes, but would require flags.) [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboBS7IKlpSVpuhbL4j10QpXjIZybhr4K0VwK0bFAbGIEIg0VjBSMFUzAAkCGkYIhkKkUUJSallmRWqzEFQvRuABqGgA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
    #_  ; Length of function argument
   U    ; Incremented
  ,     ; Range from 0 up to one less than that number, i.e. 0..len
_H      ; For each of those numbers n, get the first n elements of the function argument
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 72 bytes

```go
func(I[]int)(o[][]int){for i:=0;i<=len(I);i++{o=append(o,I[:i])};return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZA9jsMgEEZ7TkFSgUz-iIsojreOu_SIAnmNhRKDhfA2lk-SxlppD5W7bLEYO9ZKSTPzwTy9Qdy_S9M_FrXIr6IsYCWUBqqqjXXrpazcEoAvYaFMfxonV4fHWTY6RxnjSjuMDONjaqWxUB3TbaJO6a3QKMOJiqLWpKKuC_2JDMnYUXHcJbZwjdXd5PsdfGErwrAFmw1kHK4-IGOcg4v17ptGEoUtbYdxIGL6ZMiQX8GYPtEdoWRP4pn3N6EQOjWyn4PHXlXTZF7tD5Ts_vniUEZNmM7BY2-eNk4G3_QHfT_2Pw)

### Generic, 77 bytes

```go
func f[T any](I[]T)(o[][]T){for i:=0;i<=len(I);i++{o=append(o,I[:i])};return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZA_CsIwGMX3niI4JRj_xQ5irXsHwcEtZAjaSNAmJaSDlJ7EpQgewqN4FwfTtBZBl--95P14X8j1dtT1I-f7Ez-mIONSBTLLtbHjgcjs4F5YMVo8N6JQeyDoDnB1YTChbIegpqzRUmgD5DKeRnIVn1MFExTJ4bDUMc_zVB2gxgldSoaqyKS2MKrqSl--tFkJESiDyQRQBkZrQCljwdZIZc8KCkiZc2WFkCdC8mFw43_BkHzQGSZ4jsOedzd-YNIJnvfGYb9VXdKvdgeCZ199oR9tjU9747A_T2uTpq_7g7pu9Q0)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 27 bytes

```hs
i[]=[[]]
i l=i(init l)++[l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzM61jY6OjaWK1MhxzZTIzMvs0QhR1NbOzon9n9uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikKmQrShnp5p7H8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>6</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
）╶［｝）
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjA5JXUyNTc2JXVGRjNCJXVGRjVEJXVGRjA5JXVGRjUyJXVGRjQxJXVGRjU3,i=JTVCMSUyQzIlMkMzJTJDNCU1RA__,v=8)

Outputs to the stack; Linked with a trailing `ｒａｗ` so that's visible.

```
)      wrap the (currently empty) stack in an array
 ╶[}   map nothing over the prefixes of the input
    )  wrap the stack (the empty array and the prefixes) in an array
```

[2 bytes](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNCJXVGRjNEJXVGRjUyJXVGRjQxJXVGRjU3,i=JTVCMSUyQzIlMkMzJTJDNCU1RA__,v=8) without the starting empty array.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 81 bytes

```
set i -1
set a {{}}
foreach _ $argv {lappend a [lrange $argv 0 [incr i]]}
puts $a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LclLCoAgFEbhuau4g6ZBz9VExMXMBDFRayKu/c@g2eF8SVogqkSG2l58wZRzKeK4gmJ50kYNB/1Qtuy9cnv1xQZ2Wv3Q0WKcDGTWtQh/p1g/gB4DRkyYXw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 13 bytes

```
{_[0...0:#_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@786PtpAT0/PwEo5Prb2v19qakpxtEpBQXJ6LFdAUWZeSUhqcYlzYnFqcXSajkI0lwIQRMfqQGgTIxjLUMdIx1jHBC4B5BjpGMZyxcb@BwA)

### Explanation

```
{_[0...0:#_]}
{           }    block taking `_` as input
 _[        ]     index from the input
       0:#_      range from 0 to the length of `_` inclusive
   0...          range from 0 to each number that range, right exclusive
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 76 bytes

```
func[b][a: copy[[]]c: b until[append/only a copy/part b c: next c tail? c]a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYq9CsIwEMf3PsWf7lKsdcniO7geN1wuFymEJJQU7NPH4qDj72Oz0J8WiIfoetyzkmcSBy31IGJWB489tzWR1Go5TCWnA/IdpipbO/s5ZXs3KJqs6QFl4V634g0RdMWMGxbcefi5Zf7DqCXY5VVSHPsH)

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 32 bytes

```
{l->(0..l.size).map{l.take(it)}}

{ list ->
    (0..list.size).map {  // map over range [0, length of list]
        list.take(it)  // first n items of list
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY69CsMwDIT3PIXIZIMj@jeFxp0LeQlDXRBxnBCrHWr87K7jofS2u5M@aVrYkc9v44A8cehBjBT4evesJXQaqvtFGoYcXafFAdFhoI@VOJs1OmQzWUEsU8rPl4fZkBcSYgNFO90VBAwgNmseI3lbylsPbSvrxC4MqyMWrfrPChwiECMv5X5ZSrVbNyqufix2spRNykd1Umd1@QI)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 7 bytes

```
1@$O_vI
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/9/QQcU/vszzP5ClY6xjomOqYwQA)**

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 65 bytes

```
proc P {L J\ {{}}} {lmap e $L {lappend J [lappend K $e]}
list $J}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYw7CoAwEAX7nOIVuYDRU0QLe7WQmEKIumislj17XAWb94Fhckil0HkE9OAOfgSziIDTNhMibKdzJor7Ao/hny1snMSk9cqwXspHK2pYDDdOo4JDjea92g6VGLXSnS8MvWonKQ8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 57 bytes

```forth
: x here 0 begin 2dup type cr 1+ key dup c, 5 < until ; x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchLCoAwDAXAq7y9Ciq4UQ/hGazpB6WW2EJ6@khXA2Nfzn5wtqG6QuCJCSNOciFivkpCrolgGFOHmypamR4LdpSYw4MNonow2SD0/Q)

Takes bytes through STDIN and prints a series of prefixes, each terminated by a newline.

Answer (score 0):

## [str](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/str), 6 bytes

```
e;:dno
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky4p@v8/1doqJS////@M1JycfAA)

Each output line corresponds to an entry in the prefix array.

### Explanation

```
e;:dno
            -- preamble --
e           push empty string
            -- iteration --
  :         append current char to build string
   d        duplicate it
    n       push "\n"
     o      output it
            (implicitly output duplicated entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-a`, 24 bytes

```perl
say"@F[0..$_]"for-1..$#F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLJwS3aQE9PJT5WKS2/SNcQyFR2@/@fy8SIy1DBSMFYwYTLBEgaKRj@yy8oyczPK/6vm/hf19dUz8DQAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 13 bytes

```
;╗ru⌠╜H⌡M[]@o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9/60dTpRaWPehY8mjrH41HPQt/oWIf8//@jTXSMdYx0DGMB)

Explanation:

```
;╗ru⌠╜H⌡M[]@o
;╗             save a copy of input in register 0
  ru           range(1, len(input)+1)
    ⌠╜H⌡M      for i in range:
     ╜H          first i elements of input
         []@o  prepend an empty list
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 37 bytes

```
fn x->Enum.scan [[]|x],&(&2++[&1])end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@p9m@z8tT6FC1841rzRXrzg5MU8hOjq2piJWR01DzUhbO1rNMFYzNS/lv6e/XmZecUFqcolCmp5GdKwmF5qIiVGspo5CckZiUU5mcUmxlYJVYnE8mImu0lDHSMdYxwSLEUBhIx2ghf8B)

Looking at other languages, this looks rather verbose, but I'm definitely not an expert in Elixir, so please let me know if I missed something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 bytes

```apl
(0,∘⍳∘≢⊢)↑¨⊂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/@v8ahvql/wo941mnogZrCrXqizr4t6Un6FQn6egm6abX6e@qOuxal5iUk5qcGOPiFADlCdc6R6cWJOibrmfw0DnUcdMx71bgaRnYsedS3SfNQ28dCKR11N/9MetU141NsHVO/p/6ir@dB6Y6AUyJYgZyAZ4uEZDFTSu9nQgCtNPaAoNS2zIrVYHQA)

Prefix tacit function. TIO link has boxing enabled to make the output more readable.

#### How:

```apl
(0,∘⍳∘≢⊢)↑¨⊂ ⍝ Tacit fn, taking a vector as argument, which will be called ⍵ for simplicity.
         ↑   ⍝ Take the first ⍺ (left arg) elements of ⍵
          ¨⊂ ⍝ Since the ⍺ for ↑ is a vector, we enclose the ⍵ and apply ↑ to it for each of the elements in ⍺.
(      ⊢)    ⍝ Use ⍵ as argument for
      ≢      ⍝ Tally; yields the number of elements in ⍵
    ⍳∘       ⍝ Then, yield the range [1..≢⍵]
 0,∘         ⍝ and prepend a 0.
```

The function returns a vector of vectors, each with the first `[0..≢⍵]` elements of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

### Bash, 34 bytes

I output each list element on a new line as someone else did - bash only has 1-D arrays:

```
for((;c<=$#;c++)){ echo ${*:1:c};}
```

Could be 1 byte less but this does not work for null case - don't see why... c++ does not get evaluated...

```
for((;c<=$#;)){ echo ${*:1:c++};}
```

This can output text as suggested by OP:

```
C='echo -n ';A=(${1//[],[]/ });$C[[];for((c=0;c<${#A[*]};)){ B=${A[*]::++c};$C,[${B// /,}];};echo ]
```

No one should have to decode that. Here is annotated version:

```
C='echo -n '              # basically a macro to improve my golf
A=( ${1//[],[]/ } )       # convert [,] to spaces - like magic this one
$C[[]                     # echo [[] since every list needs this
for((c=0;c<${#A[*]};)){   # for all elements of list
  B=${A[*]::++c}          # make space separated list of first c elements
  $C,[${B// /,}]          # prefix with ,[ and convert space to comma
}
echo ]                    # terminate list with ]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Reticular](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/reticular), 60 bytes

```
Bql:D=:D`:E=l[:D`@d]~*[:E`b@qM[$]:D`:E`-*:E`1-:E=]:D`1+*lbo;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otyUwuzUks@v/fqTDHysXWyiXBytU2JxpIO6TE1mlFW7kmJDkU@karxIKlEnS1gIShLlARSMBQWysnKd/6/38A)

Assumes that the input list is at the top of the stack. To test input, run the following code

```
'1''2''3''4''5'lbBql:D=:D`:E=l[:D`@d]~*[:E`b@qM[$]:D`:E`-*:E`1-:E=]:D`1+*lbo;
```

### Explanation

```
B                         # Push every element from the input list to the stack.
 q                        # Reverse stack.
  l                       # Push the size of the stack to the stack.
   :D=                    # Save it as the variable D.
      :D`:E=              # Define the variable E = D.
            l             # Push D to the stack.
             [:D`@d]      # Push the function which duplicates the top D items in the stack
                    ~     # Swap the top two items in the stack
                     *    # Call the above function D number of times.



[                          ]            # Push a function that does the following:
 :E`b                                   # Put the top E items in a list.
     @q                                 # Reverse list that is at the top of the stack.
       M                                # Rotate stack so that top of stack -> bottom of stack.
        [$]:D`:E`-*                     # Delete the top D-E items from the stack.
                   :E`1-:E=             # Define E = E - 1.
                            :D`1+*      # Call the above function D+1 number of times.
                                  q     # Reverse stack.
                                   lb   # Put every item in the stack into a list.
                                     o; # Output the resulting list and exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 28 bytes

```
_.scanLeft(Seq[Int]())(_:+_)
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/EoxLVy2SSLay24sGYrXPVw)

This is longer than the [Scala answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177299/95792) that's already here, but uses a different method. Unfortunately, the `[Int]` must be used to avoid `Nothing` being inferred.

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `grouping.extras`, 25 bytes

```
[ head-clump { } prefix ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU/BDoIwDL3zFc8PgIRtJ028Gi9ejCfjYcGCJAJzbAmG8O1zkkFGD@3re69tWsrCdNrdrufLaY9Kd1bVbZXRYLTs0dPHUltQD6XJmK/SdWtwSJIxgY8RE5bYIT164k9NQRRs0SMx0IsnBwOH8MzGk4fM1sojJOIjvmezf3skZL5WFqF8XjC5O14kn2nxto2aB/2bZT3g4RqpkLkf)

Mostly a built-in. Just have to add the empty list at the beginning.

Compare to a non-trivial answer:

```
[ dup length [0,b] [ head ] with map ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY0xD4IwFIR3fsW5K5HCpImrcXExToShwhOIUGspMYbw22shhcAb7l2/u/Q9earfytxvl@v5gBcpQRVqrgtfcZFTg4Y@LYnUOqlI659UpdA4el7nwU6HHtNssDtZMKDehRGb8kXo8NQJwBAismTVCZyyeYcLFy2P2Dcb@@sjTsN5s4ULxg96EyNrJSoSuS4Q77ePBDEK4hkSfEvLai6RmEF98wc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
Sa._QY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzhRLz4w8v//aBMdBWMdBSMdBcPYf/kFJZn5ecX/dVMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```
$[a][map 0..size a=>[take a]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?dpybF1)

Answer (score 0):

## x86 opcode, 11 bytes

```
xor eax, eax
inc ecx
P:
xchg eax, esi
stosd
xchg eax, esi
stosd
inc eax
loop P
ret
```

Take `ecx(length) esi(input array) edi(output buffer)` output `(array,length)` pairs

Somehow cheaty :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 11 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 9.05 bytes

```
0TzreRz0sAI
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuharDUKqilKDqgyKHT0hIlCJBSujTXSMdYx0DGMhAgA)

##### Explanation

```python
0TzreRz0sAI  # Implicit input
0T           # Append a 0 (so the length is increased by 1)
  zr         # Length range, [0..len)
    e        # Map over this list:
     R       #   Range from 0 to this number
        sAI  #   Index this into
      z0     #   The input
             # Implicit output
```