# It took me a lot of time to make this, pls like. (YouTube Comments #1)

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

Hold up..... this isn't trolling.

---

## Background

These days on YouTube, comment sections are littered with such patterns:

```
S
St
Str
Stri
Strin
String
Strin
Stri
Str
St
S
```

where `String` is a mere placeholder and refers to any combination of characters. These patterns are usually accompanied by a `It took me a lot of time to make this, pls like` or something, and often the OP succeeds in amassing a number of likes.

---

## The Task

Although you've got a great talent of accumulating upvotes on PPCG with your charming golfing skills, you're definitely not the top choice for making witty remarks or referencing memes in YouTube comment sections. Thus, your constructive comments made with deliberate thought amass a few to no 'likes' on YouTube. *You want this to change.* So, you resort to making the abovementioned clichéd patterns to achieve your ultimate ambition, but without wasting any time trying to manually write them.

Simply put, your task is to take a string, say `s`, and output `2*s.length - 1` substrings of `s`, delimited by a newline, so as to comply with the following pattern:

(for `s` = "Hello")

```
H
He
Hel
Hell
Hello
Hell
Hel
He
H
```

---

## Input

A single string `s`. Input defaults of the community apply.
You can assume that the input string will only contain printable ASCII characters.

---

## Output

Several lines separated by a newline, constituting an appropriate pattern as explained above. Output defaults of the community apply.
Leading and trailing **blank (containing no characters or characters that cannot be seen, like a space)** lines in the output are permitted.

---

## Test Case

A multi-word test case:

```
Input => "Oh yeah yeah"

Output =>

O
Oh
Oh 
Oh y
Oh ye
Oh yea
Oh yeah
Oh yeah 
Oh yeah y
Oh yeah ye
Oh yeah yea
Oh yeah yeah
Oh yeah yea
Oh yeah ye
Oh yeah y
Oh yeah 
Oh yeah
Oh yea
Oh ye
Oh y
Oh 
Oh
O
```

Note that there are apparent distortions in the above test case's output's shape (for instance, line two and line three of the output appear the same). Those are because we can't see the trailing whitespaces. Your program need NOT to try to fix these distortions.

---

## Winning Criterion

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes in each language wins!

Comment: I am planning to make some more YouTube comments related challenges in the future; hence the `YouTube Comments #1` in the title.

Comment: Is returning a array of lines allowed?

Comment: @someone Yes, it is allowed, in accordance with standard I/O defaults

Comment: Can we take input as an array of characters and return an array of arrays of characters?

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68901/spell-out-the-revua)

Comment: Can the input be `""`? What about a single character like `"H"`? If so, what should be the output for both of those cases?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork No, the input cannot be `""`. As for `"H"`, the desired output is `H` only. I am sincerely sorry for such a late reply.

Comment: @Shaggy If the community rules allow it, then sure.

Comment: Are leading and trailing blank lines permitted?  (i.e. output is `2*s.length + 1` lines, but the first and last lines are empty)

Comment: Can we assume the input only contains chars in the ASCII 32--127 range? In particular, can we assume it doesn't contain char(0)?

Comment: @Chronocidal Yes, leading and trailing blank lines are permitted.

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, you can assume that the input will only contain printable ASCII characters. I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 120):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 32 bytes

```
,[[<]>[.>]++++++++++.,[>>]<[-]<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJzraJtYuWs8uVhsO9HSi7exibaJ1Y21i///3z1CoTE2EEAA)

The same loop is used for both halves of the pattern.

#### Explanation:

```
,             Take first input character as initial line
[             Until line to output is empty:
  [<]>        Move to beginning of line
  [.>]        Output all characters in line
  ++++++++++. Output newline
  ,           Input next character
  [>>]        Move two cells right if input character nonzero
  <[-]        Otherwise remove last character in line
  <           Move to new last character in line
]
```

Comment: That's just plain awesome. I was trying to do something in brainfuck but it came out about 10 times this long and still didn't work properly.

Comment: Never thought I'd see a challenge where the brainfuck answer was actually scoring competitively, awesome work!

Answer (score 55):

## JavaScript (ES6), 36 bytes

```javascript
f=([c,...r],s=`
`)=>c?s+f(r,s+c)+s:s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjOllHT0@vKFan2DaBK0HT1i7Zvlg7TaNIp1g7WVO72Kr4f3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGkn@GQmVqIoRQ0tT8DwA)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (             // f is a recursive function taking:
                  //   the input string split into:
  [c,             //     c   = next character (may be undefined if we've reached the end)
      ...r],      //     r[] = array of remaining characters
  s = `\n`        //   the output string s, initialized to a linefeed
) =>              // 
  c ?             // if c is defined:
    s +           //   append s (top of the ASCII art)
    f(r, s + c) + //   append the result of a recursive call to f, using r[] and s + c
    s             //   append s again (bottom of the ASCII art)
  :               // else:
    s             //   append s just once (this is the final middle row) and stop recursion
```

Comment: very nice answer :D

Comment: different OSes different sizes got to hate line endings so windows reports as 37 bytes because of `\r\n` over Unix `\n` :D

Comment: @MartinBarker On Windows, I'm using Notepad++ with the default Line Ending turned to `Unix (LF)`. Problem solved once and for all. :)

Comment: Longer than the BF solution...that's a first

Answer (score 50):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands),  <s>4</s>  3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

[<sup>*Crossed out `&nbsp;4&nbsp;` is no longer 4 :)*</sup>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170188/crossed-out-44-is-still-regular-44)

```
η.∊
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3Ha9Rx1d///7ZyhUpiZCCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVvn/3Ha9Rx1d/3UObbP/H1xSlJmXzuWRmpOTz@WfoVCZmgghAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
η     # Get the prefixes of the (implicit) input-string
 .∊   # Vertically mirror everything with the last line overlapping
      # (which implicitly joins by newlines in the legacy version of 05AB1E)
      # (and output the result implicitly)
```

In the new version of 05AB1E, and explicit `»` is required after the `η`, which is why I use the legacy version of 05AB1E here to save a byte.

---

**3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) alternative provided by *@Grimy*:**

```
ηû»
```

This version works in both the legacy and new version of 05AB1E.

[Try it online (legacy)](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3PbDuw/t/v/fP0OhMjURQgAA), [try it online (new version)](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3PbDuw/t/v/fP0OhMjURQgAA) or [verify all test cases (new version)](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVvn/3PbDuw/t/q9zaJv9/@CSosy8dC6P1JycfC7/DIXK1EQIAQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
η     # Get all prefixed of the (implicit) input-string
 û    # Palindromize each string in this list
  »   # And then join the list of strings by newlines
      # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems to 6 bytes in UTF8: `\xce\xb7\x2e\xe2\x88\x8a`

Comment: @rubenvb In UTF-8 it's indeed more. 05AB1E uses, just like some some of the programming languages used in other answers (i.e. Jelly; Japt; Charcoal) it's [own source code](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) (which is [CP-1252](http://www.cp1252.com/) in the case of 05AB1E), where each of the 256 characters it knows is a single byte.

Comment: All right, fair enough :).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen PHP seems to think that these characters are invalid for CP-1252, but could just be a PHP bug: https://3v4l.org/UC1QE

Comment: @rubenvb i'm still not convinced that CP-1252 is the answer here, see above.. =/ (PS: php-strings are byte arrays, the string length of a php string is always the number of bytes.)

Comment: @hanshenrik Tbh, I'm not 100% sure if it's CP-1252. All I know is that the linked code-page (the first link in my first comment, or the link in the bytes of the answer-title; so [this one](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)) is the code page 05AB1E uses. I've heard somewhere it's CP-1252, but maybe I'm mistaken in that and it's a custom codepage instead. I do know that those 256 characters are 1 byte each for 05AB1E programs.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen hmm, can you take a screenshot of your source code file opened in a hex editor? (if you don't have a hex editor nearby, [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/downloads.php?product=HxD20) is a great hex editor for windows systems, and [Bless](https://github.com/afrantzis/bless) is a decent hex editor for Linux ) - or can you upload your source code file on some file sharing website like http://mega.co.nz ?

Comment: come to think of it, if you're on linux, you can probably just do `cat source.file | base64 | pastebinit`

Comment: @hanshenrik Good question. It is indeed not CP-1252, but in fact the [**05AB1E encoding**](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md), which is the custom encoding it uses. The bytes of this code in hex are `08 2e 17`, which you can run and verify with the `--osabie` flag: https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnJ@SaqsUU2FgEVNhlBpTYWiu9D81OSNfQTdPQTdVQQUkr2CnUJJaXKKXmJTKVVBZkpGfZ6ygn19Qom9gmphkmKqfX5yYlJmqV1CpoKsLYcPV//@fmJSckgoA

Comment: @Adnan well that satisfies my curiosity, thanks guys!

Comment: `ηû»` for modern 05AB1E.

Comment: @Grimmy Ah, nice one. That one works in both 05AB1E versions. I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 25):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS,  <del>44</del>  <del>43</del> 39 bytes

```
00000000: d1ee ad8b d648 93b7 248a cbd0 e13a d975  .....H..$....:.|
00000010: 01fd ac86 3cb4 09cd 2186 3cb8 0d0e cd10  ....<...!.<.....
00000020: b00a cd10 e2e7 c3                        .......
```

Build and test `YT.COM` using `xxd -r` from above.

***Unassembled:***

```
D1 EE       SHR  SI, 1              ; point SI to DOS PSP at 80H (SI intialized at 100H) 
AD          LODSW                   ; load input length into AL, SI = 82H 
8B D6       MOV  DX, SI             ; save start of string pointer 
48          DEC  AX                 ; remove leading space from string length 
93          XCHG AX, BX             ; save string length in BL
B7 24       MOV  BH, '$'            ; put end-of-string marker in BH
8A CB       MOV  CL, BL             ; set up loop counter in CL
D0 E1       SHL  CL, 1              ; number of lines = 2 * string length - 1
    LINE_LOOP:
3A D9       CMP  BL, CL             ; does CL = string length?
75 01       JNZ  LINE_OUT           ; if not, go to output line
FD          STD                     ; otherwise flip DF to descend
    LINE_OUT: 
AC          LODSB                   ; increment or decrement SI
86 3C       XCHG BH, [SI]           ; swap current string byte with end of string delimiter 
B4 09       MOV  AH, 9              ; DOS API display string function 
CD 21       INT  21H                ; write substring to console 
86 3C       XCHG BH, [SI]           ; restore string byte 
B8 0E0D     MOV  AX, 0E0DH          ; AH = 0EH (BIOS tty function), AL = CR char
CD 10       INT  10H                ; write CR to console
B0 0A       MOV  AL, 0AH            ; AL = LF char
CD 10       INT  10H                ; write LF to console
E2 E6       LOOP LINE_LOOP          ; move to next line 
C3          RET                     ; return to DOS
```

***Explanation***

Loop `2 * input length - 1` for each row.  The DOS API's string display function (`INT 21H,9`) writes a `$`-terminated string to the screen, so each time through the loop the character after the last to be displayed is swapped with the end-of-string terminator.

The loop counter is compared with the string length, and if it's greater (meaning the ascending part of the output) the string/swap position is incremented, otherwise it's decremented.

Standalone PC DOS executable program, takes input string from command line.

***Output***

[image]

- -1 byte use `SHR SI, 1` instead of `MOV` - thanks to [gastropner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75886/gastropner)!
- -1 byte flipping loop comparison
- -1 byte write newline directly instead of as string
- -1 byte use `XCHG` instead of `MOV`
- -1 byte use `STD` / `LODSB` to ascend/descend SI pointer

Comment: [Most DOS flavours](http://www.fysnet.net/yourhelp.htm) have SI = 100h upon loading a COM file. This can save you a byte by replacing the first instruction with `SHR SI, 1`.

Comment: @gastropner very clever! Turns out the original won't run on DOS 1.0 anyway since it counts on CH being 0 (would cost +2 bytes to initialize, which isn't worth it just for DOS 1).  Updated with new version!

Comment: Do you have to enter the date everytime you open the terminal?

Comment: @user14492 ha, no! I just forgot to crop that part out of the DOS screenshot!

Comment: Is this assembler ? It's the first time I see this since my student time. (= long, long ago)

Comment: [Outgolfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229784/94093)

Answer (score 20):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
nZv"G@:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Py@qTMndwUrz/391n8zsVIWSjMxiheT83NzUvBJFdQA)

Please like this post for the smiley `:)` in the code it took me a lot of time to make.

```
n  % Length of the input string
Zv % Symmetric range ([1 2 ... n ... 1])
"  % For each k in above range
G  % Push input
@: % Push [1 2 ... k]
)  % Index
```

Answer (score 19):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>60</s> 52 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,n=1:s[n:]and[s[:n]]+f(s,n+1)+[s[:n]]or[s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcgxCoAgFADQvVN8mhRbbBQ8QwcQB8NEwb6iLp7@F9TyhlfniAV3oqCzu0/voG@opeoGlXXoTTcKrRWBvS8kF3@UZrqlUBpkSAiBrUeEebmPlasFaks4WOb0AA)

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 50 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,n=1:s>(x:=s[:n])and[x,*f(s,n+1),x]or[s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JckxCoAgFADQvVN8mrRcpCUEu0IHEAfDpMC@8m2w01vQ8paXn/tIOM2ZWgs6umvzDopALVVZWFW6GIWWO/SmiiGwr0bJRbWJTLEtJIIIJ0Jg/XrAs7ufnqsOMp14s8jbCw)

Comment: Does this depend on a forthcoming feature of 3.8? Which feature?

Comment: @alexis This is using an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/): `x:=s[:n]`.

Comment: Ah, I see it now thanks :-) I've read about the feature before, looking forward to it. Still miss it from my C days...

Comment: These don't print the output though. They just make the array, right?

Comment: @JadenTravnik Python automatically dupms the last expression result if running interactively through a console

Comment: @JadenTravnik It's a lambda expression (an anonymous function), and functions are allowed by default.

Answer (score 16):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 11 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Returns a space-padded character matrix.

```
[:(}:,|.)]\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8D/aSqPWSqdGTzM25r8ml5KegnqarZ66go5CrZVCWjEXV2pyRr5CmoJ6cElRZl66Opzvn6FQmZoIIdT/AwA)

`]\` the list of prefixes

`[:(`…`)` apply the following function to that list

`|.` the reverse list

`,` prepended with

`}:` the curtailed (without last item) list

Comment: `[:(` and `}:,|` look so sad…

Comment: But it's (}: which is a happy person with a fancy mustache

Answer (score 13):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 31 bytes

```perl6
{[\~](@_)[0...@_-1...0]}o*.comb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzo6pi5WwyFeM9pAT0/PIV7XEEgZxNbma@kl5@cm/bfmStNQCi4pysxLV9K0s9MrTqwEC/lnKFSmJkIImMR/AA)

Anonymous code block that takes a string and returns a list of lines.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                      }o*.comb   # Pass the list of characters into the codeblock
 [\~](@_)                 # Triangular reduce by concatenation
                          # e.g. The list [1,2,3,4] turns into [1,12,123,1234]
         [0...@_-1        # Return the elements from 0 to length of string minus 1
                  ...0]   # And back down to 0
```

Comment: It's funny that these days even golfed Perl is among the most readable contestants.

Comment: @ceasedtoturncounterclockwis Well, this is Perl 6. The [Perl 5 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180527/76162) is still unreadable

Answer (score 11):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [-R](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/command-line-flags-on-front-ends/14339#14339), 4 bytes

```
å+ ê
```

Cumulative reduce on a string.

*-1 byte thanks to @Shaggy*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///BSbYXDq/7/V/LPUKhMTYQQSly6QQA)

Comment: Sceptic about the "-R" that has to be included in the string (without it the output doesnt work)

Comment: @FlyingThunder Be a skeptic no more :) [see here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/20438)

Comment: @Quintec, I've taken to linking the flags in my solution headers to that meta post to try to preempt these sorts of comments.

Comment: Pretty sure convention is <language> + `-flag` or <language> `-flag`. Also, :| I forgot cumulative reduce was a thing, I swear I skipped over it every time I saw it

Comment: @ASCII-only Same, I only remembered it because I was thinking how I would solve this in APL and said "I wonder if Japt has this builtin". Also, didn't I use <language> `-flag`?

Comment: @Quintec but you linked to a meta post, not enclosed it in a codeblock (actually, you can even do both)

Answer (score 10):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-R`, <s>9</s> 7 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)

```
Êõ@¯XÃê
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//3DX4a0Oh9ZHHG4@vOr/fyX/DIXK1EQIocSlGwQA)

Comment: [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//3DX4a0Oh9ZHHG4@vOr/fyX/DIXK1EQIocSlGwQA)

Comment: @Shaggy oh wait... `Ã` is a thing

Comment: Another 300 rep on its way as soon as this question is eligible for a bounty.

Comment: [5 bytes? (different approach)](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=rOUrIOo=&input=Ik9oIHllYWggeWVhaCIgLVI=)

Comment: @Quintec, cumulative reduce works on strings, too, so you don't need to split at the start. I'd also say that's different enough to warrant posting it yourself.

Comment: @Shaggy Ok, will do.

Answer (score 10):

## Perl 5 (`-p`), 26 bytes

```
s,.,$\=$`.$/.$\;"$`$&
",ge
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YR09HJcZWJUFPRV9PJcZaSSVBRY1LSSc99f9/j9ScnPx/@QUlmfl5xf91C/7r@prqGRgCAA)

Answer (score 9):

## Haskell, <del>52</del> <del>50</del> 44 bytes

```
f x=unlines$init<>reverse$scanr(\_->init)x x
```

- -2 bytes by a variant of [Ørjan Johansen's trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177153/81540)
- -6 bytes by [taking advantage of `instance Semigroup b => Semigroup (a -> b)`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177774/81540)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xCsJAEER7v2KQFAmYgGJhoQFRUCsLLQU5w8YsXu7C7UWTr48nkV1eMTs7Uyl5kdYD1411HnvlVXahmp/Otg3ieJ0nCdIUvmJBWGt0D0MFiSjX40GFaoVwPZ1/V/GsdfDgcNxhlS3CYBueyr@wzOazMepj3SuQfQVjMbZLNpnUig02aFp/8Q4RSkzPFXpSI6ZDiW7TGs2GJGLDfp07epMTiqRQxsW3e5r/9KRDNwxf)

Comment: Welcome to the site.  `inits` requires an import to be used so you are going to need to add `import Data.List` or something similar.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic Wasn't sure if that was necessary to count or not. Added, thanks!

Comment: Also I should mention we have [a chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66515/of-monads-and-men) for talking Haskell golfing.  If you have any thoughts or questions that's a great place.

Comment: I can't believe you came up with exactly what I was going to post:
```import Data.List
putStr.unlines.((++)<*>reverse.init).tail.inits```

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>79</s> <s>65</s> <s>62</s> 58 bytes

```r
write(substring(s<-scan(,""),1,c(1:(r=nchar(s)),r-1:r)),1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVo7g0qbikKDMvXaPYRrc4OTFPQ0dJSVPHUCdZw9BKo8g2LzkjsUijWFNTp0jX0KoISBtq/g8G6/gPAA)

*-14 by Giuseppe's superior function knowledge*

*-3 with cleaner indexing*

*-4 thanks to Nick Kennedy and Giuseppe's move to `scan` and `write`*

Avoiding loops (and `substr`) is nice.

Comment: loops are thoroughly unnecessary, as is `sapply` -- `substring` will do what you want (with an additional trailing empty line), and for [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NYMzmxRKO4NKm4pCgzL12jWMdQJ1nD0CovOSOxCCirA2NYGeoaamrqFKcW2CpxKWn@T9NQCgZrAbIB)! I definitely wouldn't have thought of `substring` if I hadn't seen your nice use of `substr` here.

Comment: Haha, good catch! I think I've learned more about alternate functions for the same job from your edits than anywhere else at this point.

Comment: Haha, R has a stupid amount of synonyms with subtle differences. Every time I feel like I know the best tool for the job, I find something else that's slightly better in a weird edge case...

Comment: How about [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVo7g0qbikKDMvXaPYRrc4OTFPQ0dJSVPHUCdZw9BKo8g2LzkjsUijWFNTp0jX0KoISAOl/weDtfwHAA "R – Try It Online") using `scan` and `write`? Only 59 bytes!

Comment: @NickKennedy 58 bytes if you replace `""` with `1`.

Comment: @Giuseppe thanks, didn’t know that. It also seems that using 2 outputs to stderr.

Comment: @NickKennedy that's neat, I couldn't find a way to use `scan` that didn't add more bytes. Will have to look into how `write` works, never really used it before.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 48 bytes

```python
lambda s,r='':(l:=[r:=r+c for c in s])+l[-2::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcixCoAgEADQva84WlKsoVriwC@xBrOswEwuB/t6wze@8MXz8eMUKFs5Z6fvddPwtiSbBplDqQglCQP2ITBweXgXLpzqBsSuX3LpVNqyWq9m2@1Rc6wg0OUjSzz/)

Uses [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) with `:=` to [accumulate a list of prefixes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180041/20260) and then again to save the result to concatenate its reverse (without the first char).

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 51 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,l=[]:s and f(s[:-1],[s]+l)or l+l[-2::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcoxDoAgDEDR3VM0TBB0kJHEkxAGEFGTWog46Omrjv/l1@faChnmPGE4YgrQepyctw0CJciyOTuMvnfNa1TlBNToBmN/5Pz1DTt9mwhxTktehbId1HOnS96KXw)

We almost have the following nice 45-byte solution, but it has the original string twice and I don't see a short way to fix this.

```python
f=lambda s,l=[]:s and f(s[:-1],[s]+l+[s])or l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRoVgnxzY61qpYITEvRSFNozjaStcwVie6OFY7RxtIauYXKeT8TwOSFQqZeUAFSolJySmpaelKmlZcCgVFmXklGhWa/wE)

Comment: Wouldn't you need to add some newline and print to get the desired output?

Comment: Something like `print('\n'.join(f(s)))`  ?

Comment: @JadenTravnik The community defaults (which this challenge follows) [allow for functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/20260) in addition to programs. And the challenge author said in the comments that they are OK with a list of strings within joining as [allowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17095/20260), though I myself don't like this as a default and have downvoted it. See also the [Python rules summary](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11925/20260).

Comment: Huh. Ok, thanks for pointing that out. Im new ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.
If thats the case, here is a competing 45-byte solution: `x=[s[:i+1]for i in range(len(s))];x+x[-2::-1]`

Comment: @JadenTravnik No problem, the rules are unfortunately scattered over the place. Your example though is a snippet which are not allowed. It needs to do input and output like `s=input();x=[s[:i+1]for i in range(len(s))];print x+x[-2::-1]`. See the [examples at the top here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11925/20260).

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [@JonathanAllan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)!*

```
¹ƤŒḄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QzmNLjk56uKPl/@H2yP//lTyAwvmKSgA) I think this is my second Jelly answer? <s>I don't know if this is optimal.</s> I am more convinced of it being optimal. Returns an array of lines.

### Explanation

```
¹ƤŒḄ     input: "Hi!"
¹Ƥ       prefixes of the input: [["H"], ["H", "i"], ["H", "i", "!"]]
  ŒḄ     bounce, using each array: [["H"], ["H", "i"], ["H", "i", "!"], ["H", "i"], ["H"]]
```

Another approach, proposed by @JonathanAllan, is `;\ŒḄ`, which cumulatively reduces (`\`) concatenation (`;`), which is another way to generate prefixes.

Comment: We are allowed to yield an array of lines, so you can bump `Y` out of the code (I'd make the footer either `ÇY` or `ÇŒṘ` to avoid a full-program's implicit smashing print). On a side-note this is also equivalently implemented as `;\ŒḄ` for the same byte-count (also you can pass the argument as`"blah"` as Jelly interprets this as a list of characters - yours is actually a list of lists of characters, as you'll see if you make the footer `ÇŒṘ`)

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks! very interesting :)

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>123</s> <s>109</s> <s>94</s> <s>84</s> 74 bytes

Assumes we can return a char array array (I believe we can, as a char array is a valid representation for a string and a string array is a valid representation for multiple lines)

```cs
a=>new int[a.Length*2-1].Select((b,i)=>a.SkipLast(Math.Abs(a.Length-i-1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BasJAEEDvfsXixdmSLNhrzIKIAUtKCyn00HqYLIMZjBPZXVv9@nRpELwMD@Yx81zIXeCxuohbhehZDtluK5cTeWx7Wj2y69Bba1VVlSOWVuhXscQvNDXJIXZPz/lybxrqyUWANmNdWjTNkc81hgivGDuzbgPc/ZzzpdZ6LGY/6JWnoMp0GuZvnboRTmOui9l7ioqQ9ok3g4ShJ/PpOVLNQjA1m5eBBRbfssiSeI@4TpHNvwJX8zGsvccbpK@PXIx/)

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 5 bytes

```
Ｇ^Ｌθθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8gP6cyPT9PwypOR8EnNS@9JEOjUFNHoVDT@v9//wyFytRECMH1X7csBwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: `Ｇ` draws a filled polygon, `^` specifies that the sides are down right and down left (the polygon then automatically closes itself), `Ｌθ` specifies the length of those sides as being the length of the original input and the final `θ` specifies the fill string.

Answer (score 5):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 15 bytes

```
Bounce@Prefixes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@98pvzQvOdUhoCg1LbMitfh/Wj5QVMErPzNPLSdNQVlZIY2LK6AoM68kOi0/Wsk/Q6EyNTFDUSk29j8A)

Pretty simple. `Bounce`s (appends reverse without center) the `Prefixes` of the input.

Alternatively, **21 bytes:** `Bounce@{_[0..0:~-#_]}`, re-implementing prefix.

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (v2), 6 bytes

```
a₀ᶠ⊆.↔
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/P/FRU8PDbQsedbXpPWqb8v@/UmISUDYxBUQp/Y8CAA)

Function submission, returning an array of lines. Loosely based on [@Fatalize's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180542/76359).

### Explanation

```
a₀ᶠ⊆.↔
    .↔  Find a palindrome
   ⊆      that contains, in order,
  ᶠ       all
a₀        prefixes of {the input}
```

Tiebreak order here is set by the `⊆`, which, when used with this flow pattern, prefers [the shortest possible output, tiebroken by placing the given elements as early as possible](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1FX28NtCw5tOrTp//9oQx0jHWMdk9j/UQA). The shortest possible output is what we want here (due to it not being possible to have any duplicate prefixes), and placing the given elements (i.e. the prefixes) as early as possible will place them in the first half (rounded up) of the output. Given that we're also requiring them to be placed in the same order, we happen to get exactly the pattern we need even though the description we gave Brachylog is very general; the tiebreaks happen to work out exactly right, causing Brachylog to pick the output we want rather than some other output that obeys the description.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Returns list of strings.

```apl
(⊢,1↓⌽),\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X@NR1yIdw0dtkx/17NXUifmf9qhtwqPevkd9Uz39H3U1H1pv/KhtIpAXHOQMJEM8PIP/pymoB5cUZealq3MBmf4ZCpWpiRBCHQA)

`,\` the list of prefixes (lit, the cumulative concatenation)

`(`…`)` apply the following function to that list:

`⌽` the reversed list

`1↓` drop the first item

`,` prepend

`⊢` the unmodified list

Answer (score 4):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <strike>31</strike> 35 bytes

```
:x
h
s/.\n.*\|.$//
/^$/{x;q}
H
G
bx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/36qCK4OrWF8vJk9PS1@fSz9ORb@6wrqwlsuDy50rqeL//5DU4pLMvHSFjNScnHwA)

## Explanation

At the beginning of each iteration of the loop, pattern space is some "central chunk" of the desired output, and each loop adds a shortened copy to the top and bottom.

```
:x                 
h                  Copy the current chunk to hold space
s/.\n.*\|.$//      Remove the last letter of the first line, and all other lines (if there are any)
/^$/{x;q}          If pattern space is empty we're done; output hold space
H                  Add the shortened line to the end of hold space
G                  and add the new hold space to pattern space.
bx
```

Comment: Nice one, but the the middle line (the full original input) seems to be output 3 times. At least with GNU `sed`. Same on TIO. Which `sed` implementation you use and how you pass it the input? (BTW, changing the substitution to `s/.\n.*\|.$//` fixes it.)

Comment: Ah, you're right. It's not a problem with my `sed` implementation (using GNU version 4.2.1) , I just didn't notice the bug. I've played around with some other fixes and can't find anything that adds fewer than four bytes so I'm adopting your fix, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 46 bytes

```powershell
($l=$args|% t*y|%{($s+=$_);++$i})+$l[$i..0]|gu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqZgq1D9X0Mlx1YlsSi9uEZVoUSrska1WkOlWNtWJV7TWltbJbNWU1slJ1olU0/PILYmvfR/LReXGlCnB9CEfDBLyT9DoTI1EUIo/QcA)

---

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 42 bytes (YouTube special, dirty)

It is known that the maximum length of a comment on youtube is 10,000 characters. Ok, use this as the upper limit.

```powershell
($l=$args|% t*y|%{($s+=$_)})+$l[1e4..0]|gu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqZgq1D9X0Mlx1YlsSi9uEZVoUSrska1WkOlWNtWJV6zVlNbJSfaMNVET88gtia99H8tF5caUJcHUHc@mKXkn6FQmZoIIZT@AwA)

Answer (score 4):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC-DOS, 33 bytes

Hexdump:

```
00000000: bf 82 00 91 89 fa e8 0a 00 74 06 41 eb f8 e8 02  .........t.A....
00000010: 00 e2 fb b4 40 cd 21 b0 0d ae cd 29 b0 0a cd 29  ....@.!....)...)
00000020: c3                                               .
```

Commented assembly:

```lisp
        [org 0x100]
start:
        ; DI <- first command line argument
        mov     di, 0x0082
        ; DOS startup state abuse 1: set CX to zero by swapping AX (0x0000)
        xchg    cx, ax
        ; DX <- DI
        mov     dx, di
.loop1:
        ; A multitasking loop.
        ; This both prints the string up to the full length and counts
        ; the chars by scanning for '\r'.

        ; Print DS:DX(CX)
        ; We test for the end of string when printing
        ; the newline by using SCASB.
        call    putsn
        ; If the SCASB returned true, break to the end of .loop2
        ; We don't go to the top because it would print the full
        ; length string twice.
        jz      .next
        ; Increment the length and character counter
        inc     cx
        ; Loop to loop1
        jmp     .loop1
        
.loop2: ; Shortening loop
        ; Print
        call    putsn
.next:
        ; while (--CX)
        loop    .loop2
        ; Fallthrough: prints an empty line (as CX is 0) and exits

        ; Prints CX chars from DX, followed by a newline.
putsn:
        ; DOS startup state abuse 2: BX is 0x0000.
        ; DOS lets you write to STDIN and it still prints to the screen.
        ; Why? I have no idea. It's very convenient though. Note that
        ; this behavior is consistent on DOS 6.22 and FreeDOS 1.3rc4.
        ;
        ; write(0, argv, CX)
        mov     ah, 0x40
        int     0x21
        ; Print \r\n with INT 29h
        mov     al, 13
        ; Since we have \r in AL, we can use SCASB to check
        ; for the end of the string when we return.
        ; Interrupts save the flags.
        ;
        ; Yes, this reads out of bounds on the second loop,
        ; but it is DOS, who cares?
        scasb
        int     0x29
        mov     al, 10
        int     0x29
        ret
```

To be even with 640KB, I also used the command line arguments, but I made some changes:

1. I use `write` (`21:40`) instead of `puts` (`21:09`). While it does require manually printing a newline, it lets me manually control the length just by changing CX.
2. I count the length of the command line arguments on the fly.
3. I did some other tricks.

This abuses the newline rule: it actually prints empty strings at the start and end.

[image: What did you expect?]

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>68</s> <s>67</s> <s>64</s> 59 bytes

thanks @ceilingcat for -6
thanks @gastropner for -5

```c
i,j;f(char*s){for(j=1;i+=j;puts(""))j-=2*!s[write(1,s,i)];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY2xDoIwGITn9ilKE5MWSxA307C7OToAJk0t8DdQDK0xSnh2hLh7w930faeTRutlAWFlzXSrxtjzqR5GZvNMwj638vEMnlHKuU3yYxz54jVCMCwTXgCv5LxsFNFFdthSSYx7BY7xCSOvlasZ3RW30lWlo4JoLjFaj9bBKE0JOAigOviAa1ZHhVFvem8C04IcBDlt2ZC/pnm5tORt1K/w2XTdIMh1GLt79AU)

Comment: Does not appear to be reusable.

Comment: @gastropner what do you mean, not reusable?

Comment: @Baldrickk If you call the function again with a new string, it doesn't work.

Comment: @gastropner so?  Since when was that a requirement? It works fine running the program again with a new string.

Comment: @Baldrickk [https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4940/758869](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4940/75886)

Comment: Umm... if you want to reusable version you can make it by adding `j=0` 3 bytes in the first for statement.

Comment: [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##fY2xDoIwGITn9ilKE5MWSxA307C7OToAJk0t8DdQDK0xSnh2hLh7w930faeTRutlAWFlzXSrxtjzqR5GZvNMwj638vEMnlHKuU3yYxz54jVCMCwTXgCv5LxsFNFFdthSSYx7BY7xCSOvlasZ3RW30lWlo4JoLjFaj9bBKE0JOAigOviAa1ZHhVFvem8C04IcBDlt2ZC/pnm5tORt1K/w2XTdIMh1GLt79AU "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>51</s> <s>42</s> 40 bytes

```ruby
f=->s,i=1{s[i]?[t=s[0,i],*f[s,i+1],t]:s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W165YJ9PWsLo4OjPWPrrEtjjaQCczVkcrLRoorm0Yq1MSa1Vc@7@gtKRYIS1ayT9DoTI1EUIoxf4HAA)

Thanks to Doorknob for -2 bytes.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by replacing `...` with `,`

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
]\,[:}.@|.]\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8D82RifaqlbPoUYvNua/JpeSnoJ6mq2euoKOQq2VQloxF1dqcka@QpqCenBJUWZeujqc75@hUJmaCCHU/wMA)

Still 1 byte longer than Adám's

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>12</s> 11  bytes

-1 byte thanks to ngn

```
{x,1_|x}@,\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qukLHML6motZBJ@Z/moKSf4ZCZWoihFD6DwA)

Comment: Did I [outgolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180521/43319) the master‽

Comment: @Adám  I'm far from being a J master :) There are many J coders here better than I am.

Comment: -1 byte for oK: [`{x,1_|x}@,\ `](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qukLHML6motZBJ@Z/moKSf4ZCZWoihFD6DwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 90 bytes

This can probably be golfed alot more, [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180514/84942) already has a way shorter one but I had fun atleast!

```javascript
s=>{a=[];for(c=s.length-1;c--;)a[c]=s.slice(0,c+1);return[...a,s,...a.reverse()].join`\n`}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JchRCgIhEIDhq/S2Sjq0z2JX6ACbsDKNuy6i4dhCRGe3opf/g3/zu2es8d50LjfqwXa255e3kzOhVIGWIVFe2qpHg1ob6Sd038kpIomTwuMoTaX2qHkCAK9Y/YBKO1UmIR1sJeb5mud3x5K5JIJUFhHEcFkPT/L/DFKa/gE)

Answer (score 3):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 118 bytes

```
	N =INPUT
	L =1
1	X =LT(X,SIZE(N)) X + 1	:F(D)
O	N ARB . OUTPUT POS(X)	:($L)
D	X =GT(X) X - 1	:F(END)
	L ='D'	:(O)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NPwdbTLyA0hIvTR8HWkMuQM0LB1idEI0In2DPKVcNPU1MhQkFbwZDTyk3DRZPLH6jeMchJQU/BPzQEqEshwD9YI0KT00pDxUeTywWk2R2oGaRJF6LJ1Q@oDWS2uos6UJm/JhdQ5P//4JKizLx0AA)

There appears to be a bug in this implementation of SNOBOL; attempting to replace the label `D` with the label `2` causes an error, although the manual for Vanilla SNOBOL indicates that (emphasis added)

> If a label is present, it must begin with the first character of the line. Labels provide a name for the statement, and serve as the target for transfer of control from the GOTO field of any statement. **Labels must begin with a letter or digit, optionally followed by an arbitrary string of characters.** The label field is terminated by the character blank, tab, or semicolon. If the first character of a line is blank or tab, the label field is absent.

My supposition is that the CSNOBOL interpreter only supports a single label that begins with an integer.

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, 31 bytes

Prompts for input of string:

```
 ⊃((⍳n),1↓⌽⍳n)↑¨(¯1+2×n←⍴s)⍴⊂s←⎕
```

Explanation:

```
(¯1+2×n←⍴s)⍴⊂s create a nested vector of the string of length =1+2x length of string

((⍳n),1↓⌽⍳n)↑¨ progressively select elements from each element of the nested vector 
              following the pattern 1  2 ...to n to n-1 ... 1

⊃ convert nested vector into a 2d array.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>67</s> 61 bytes

```fs
let l=s.Length
[1..l*2-1]|>Seq.map(fun i->s.[..l-abs(i-l)-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYq9CsIwEID3PsVxILRCDurezA5uHatDDEkNnJfai1vfPQbH7yeq8XkPlUMBhQnwGpgz/pknpVuQtby6ZSTi88WMj8PO4UNvt/XxK5CMVVpaM@6pfTI8tGWoh4W57ElW8lm8K4B3QWh2a7JEATwpdvUH)

Input is a `string` and output is a `seq<string>`

Another solution could be `let f(s:string)=for i=1 to s.Length*2-1 do printfn"%s"s.[..s.Length-abs(i-s.Length)-1]` for 80ish bytes... I am not sure that it is worth looking into.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 36 bytes

```hs
foldr(\h l->(h:)<$>[]:l++min[[]]l)[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBDkAwEADAr2ykh4r0A4IXcHJse1ilKrbVFN@3ZgLe50bEvjfsL1qLNAFIDTK0dScGbVtqmngkra2lWluOeCToIWKeIL/P/JQxgQAPFS5u3Sr@nCfcb1Yu5x8)

Outputs a list of lines.

**[Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 37 bytes**

```hs
f[c]=[[c]]
f(h:t)=(h:)<$>"":f t++[""]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/Py06OdY2GkjEcqVpZFiVaNoCSU0bFTslJas0hRJt7Wglpdj/uYmZeQq2CrmJBb4KBaUlwSVFPnkKKgppCkqJSckpqUr/AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>62</s> <s>60</s> 58 bytes

-2 bytes by using the `write()` approach of [jaeyong-sung](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/77388/jaeyong-sung)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180512/75886).

```c
i,d;f(char*s){for(d=1;write(1,s,i+=d-=!s[i]*2);puts(""));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9TJ8U6TSM5I7FIq1izOi2/SCPF1tC6vCizJFXDUKdYJ1PbNkXXVrE4OjNWy0jTuqC0pFhDSUlT07r2f2ZeiUJuYmaehiZXNRdnmoaSR2pOTr6SprUCRJWuri6QA5bxz1CoTE2EEFgVBJcUZealY0jV/gcA)

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 79 bytes

```php
function y($s,$l=1){echo$t=substr($s,0,$l)."
",$l<strlen($s)?y($s,$l+1).$t:'';}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MUKjVUinVUcmwNNatTkzPyVUpsi0uTikuKQMIGQAlNPSUuJSBtAxTLSc0DCmvaQ/VoG2rqqZRYqatb1/6v1FAPLinKzEtX17Tm4gKZpKAUk6cEZANlPFJzcvKxSfhnKFSmJkIIoPx/AA)

Recursive in PHP as a function.  Ungolfed version:

```php
function y( $s, $l=1 ) {
    echo $t = substr( $s, 0, $l ) . "\n";
    if ( $l < strlen( $s ) ) {
        y( $s, $l+1 );
        echo $t;
    }
}
```

Call as `y('String')` outputs:

```php
S
St
Str
Stri
Strin
String
Strin
Stri
Str
St
S
```

Or **69 bytes** iterative with `php -nF` input as STDIN (basically a port of several other answers).

```php
while(++$x<2*$l=strlen($s=$argn))echo substr($s,0,$l-abs($x-$l)),"
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBCoAgEADvvWKJhbQMomtKT@gNFtIGS4kW1est6jKHGcaTT7r35AFtmFcwUAwEt7M/ii6dtLATVYWXbktkE/fAbhUYzXdI6SbaIB7jG16rGoVc2zEKvGpkKVWe5V1KDw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Assembly (nasm, x64, Linux)], <strike>35</strike> 32 bytes

This is a function that takes a string (Pointer in RSI) and it's length (number in ebp), and outputs the required string to STDOUT.

EDI and EDX *MUST* be 0

```
ytc:
	;Actual setup
	inc ebp
	inc edi ;FD for STDOUT
	push rdi ;Value to add/subtract
	mov bl, 0Ah
.lp:
	add edx, [rsp] ;Str Length +- 1
	jz .end
	cmp edx, ebp
	jne .clp
	push -1
.clp:
	xchg [rsi+rdx-1], bl
	mov al, 1
	syscall
	xchg [rsi+rdx-1], bl
	jmp .lp
.end:
	ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHLTsMwEDxnv2LptUlohDiQnEorBBISqC0IqaoqxzZJKuch24GUny9r4vbGJZN9eGZ3lhkj61wdo4aZ@nQqVJszhXtjmbYAI6YwtBq1qEL38cHgggHq9gu1oYqVxlK7/svIvAtRfLda4JZyeyWbHWZrq6umQAoKWwJnSuHRcoBssUghW80/UpwR3ntceFye8WnENaGn6tqqsVK7R6@X5PPIn63uLil1TiW3joNUUwiyObc9LWuk7TsIqoa7uf2PqDB7WOIn7breLF/eNhB0vSmdAZi9M9VLtC0yIa5Nn1vNuIXAbZ6rEGfzEmLVkQTViYqs2mrTjQ748XAaYQLB4Qdj2QgIeN2NnX8jHBqJMVedF40ScBERDrwsHFk1JfOjZBeS4CjMSJgIzdE4Y//rPJAMjQZOlOi0pCNvjeS2ahuMBbNsB@dLpiBynDxKpdoQ6ZZKXE3AX5NqApOb0@kX)

Answer (score 3):

## BASH (+ GNU coreutils) 72 bytes

Takes input string from STDIN (one line)

```
read s;for i in `seq ${#s};seq $((${#s}-1)) -1 1`;do echo ${s:0:$i};done
```

example:

```
echo "Oh yeah yeah" | ./script.sh
```

output:

```
O
Oh
Oh
Oh y
Oh ye
Oh yea
Oh yeah
Oh yeah
Oh yeah y
Oh yeah ye
Oh yeah yea
Oh yeah yeah
Oh yeah yea
Oh yeah ye
Oh yeah y
Oh yeah
Oh yeah
Oh yea
Oh ye
Oh y
Oh
Oh
O
```

### Explanation:

```
# read string from STDIN into variable $s
read s

# `seq ${#s}` : sequence of numbers from 1 to length of string followed by
# `seq $((${#s}-1)) -1 1` : sequence of numbers from length-1 downto 1

# loop through sequence
for i in `seq ${#s};seq $((${#s}-1)) -1 1`;do

    # print substring of $s from position 0 to i
    echo ${s:0:$i}

# end of loop
done
```

Comment: You can squish it down to 67 bytes... `read s;for i in \`seq ${#s};seq $[${#s}-1] -1 1\`;{ echo ${s:0:$i};}` using some bash golf tricks. Example: https://ideone.com/Pw94LT

Comment: I golfed it down to 65 in bash using weird iterators! Here's my solution... [tio.run](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAu68w8uAWQnRUrLdYGSqooHsJ8e02c5nqxijWPLQS1KzNtZM3F87VvuAR1lUBNOI14zwceArhZQAg9naZslblJn1XfQyTMjpb6J1jtAkn@pnvBw)

Answer (score 2):

### Julia, 40 bytes

```julia
s->(a=cumprod([s...]);[a;a[end-1:-1:1]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcJBCoAgEADAr4SnXUjBa2Ln/iAelkrY2FSsoN9bwxyPMNm3p8H3S89Afn3O2soG4TLGRHSBHIU9b9pOfxsj9pMqsJ5r43xLBsYxgVp2kaIQ@wc)

Gets the first half by taking the cumulative product (`*` is string concatenation in Julia) of the array of characters, then adds this array to itself reversed minus the first element.

Thanks to [@Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l) for 4 bytes.

Comment: In modern Julia, `cumprod` and `reverse` accept string inputs, [bringing the solution to 32 bytes.](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBkjQFW4WlpSVpuhY3FYp17TQSbZNLcwuK8lM0ijWtoxOti1LLUouKUzUSNWM1Ier25iYWaGTq2hUUZeaV5ORpZGrqpGkoeaTm5OQraULVLFgAoQE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 58 bytes

```matlab
for k=1:(n=nnz(s=input(''))*2)-1
disp(s(1:min(k,n-k)))
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADA3Vfg1NbIgCMJP/ATBjA2hEIEHfw83hXfjzeOcZZbJWcsihP5sDmW@nQEIFo20mYK3Co2NDazYFpFJyKaooQxYOcUVb@4KV9yjtJn@AE)

Comment: I came up with essentially the same answer in MATLAB before I saw yours, but you get to take shortcuts in Octave with those compound assignments saving several bytes... I did briefly consider if any char maps to zero, such that `nnz` would miss it?

Comment: @Wolfie Somehow I assumed the input would not contain char(0), but you are right, it might be the case. I've asked for the OP if we can assume the standard ASCII range 32--127

Comment: @Wolfie Confirmed: only printable ASCII

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
a₀ᶠ;Lc.↔
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/qG3Do6bGh7s6H26d8D/xUVPDw20LrH2S9R61Tfn/X8k/Q6EyNRFCKP0HAA)

#### Explanation

```
a₀ᶠ          Find all prefixes of the input
   ;Lc.      The output is that list of prefixes with something unknown appended at the end
      .↔     The output reversed is itself (i.e. it's a palindrome)
```

Answer (score 2):

### [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), 103 bytes

```
1 INPUT S$:N=1
2 PRINT LEFT$(S$,N):IF N<LEN(S$) THEN N=N+1:GOTO 2
3 N=N-1:PRINT LEFT$(S$,N):IF N>1 THEN 3
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>82</s> 81 bytes

```cs
x=>{for(int l=x.Length,i=0;i<l*2-1;)WriteLine(x.Substring(0,l-Math.Abs(++i-l)));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcuxCsMgEADQPV8RMmkTJe1qDGTrkE4dOjeiycFxgl5AKP12O/Ttz2XlMtTFMUSaMiegfW6DrcXOHyBu0Ra9etr5GMCOJsQkDEx4uamrka8E7FcgL4p@ntu/i3FA9XjzoZcti74HhVJK862maYLo7h4xdrL@AA)

String as input and output to std

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 6 bytes

```
BE 27 4F 5F 2B 58
```

[Try it here!](https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.%3E%27O_%2BX&input=Hello&warnings=1&hex=0)

```
        - input() (implicit)
.>      - prefixes(^) (1 byte)
  'O_   - ^[:-1], reversed(^)
     +  - [^]
      X - "\n".join(reversed(^))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 7 bytes

```
£rñ{l<n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///Q4qLDG6tzbPL@/1fyz1CoTE2EEEr/AQ)

### Explanation

```
£         length of array/string with pop
 r        range(0, n)
  ñ       pop(a), push palindromize(a) string/list/number
   {      start block or arbitrary length
    l     read string from input
     <    slice input string at index
      n   newline char
```

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish),  <s>44</s>  41 bytes

```
i:0(?^l&}21.>ao&~
:o}1&:1-&) ?^
l&21.>~{~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9PKQMM@Lket1shQzy4xX62Oyyq/1lDNylBXTVPBPo4rRw0kUVdd9/9/QFFqWmYFAA)

Answer (score 2):

### VBA, <s>54</s> 51 Bytes

(-3 bytes now that leading & trailing 0-character lines are confirmed as permitted)

```vb
x=Len([A1]):For i=-x To x:?Left([A1],x-abs(i)):Next
```

Just a simple loop from -Length to Length, omitting that many Absolute characters from the end each time

Input is cell A1 of the ActiveSheet.  Output and Code are in the Immediate window

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 62 bytes

```
{s->s.indices.map{s.take(it+1)}.let{it+it.reversed().drop(1)}}
```

Could probably be golfed more, but this is what I came up with.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5NCoNADIX3niJ0NUNxoFup9gJCFz3B4MQ2qFFmUqGIZ7fjz6LNIiR8L3mv6aUlXkbbQtV3HbJkoB7iiZ8a0gJKCnLd9wLyZQppEQyxowqD6ewwBSO2QUVyvujZtChTHEmMxxF9QKe0cb4fVKTzUr8ZOkusNEwJxFp9BYNADh6tK4kxslsGp9PGh2gsLasjm1q1Wm@o7r2K0RGI4R8fv3/vV@F@Nifzcn/BB@3evg)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
S+o↔hḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1g7/1HblIyHOxb///9fySM1JydfRyE8vygnRQkA)

Takes input as an argument.

```
S      Apply the first argument to the third argument and to the second argument applied to the third argument:
 +     concatenation,
 o     the composition of
  ↔    reversal
  h    with removal of the last element,
 ḣ     every prefix of
       the input.
```

...I may need to not try to explain combinators in plain English.

Comment: I feel like there might be a way to shave a byte off this on account of this having used both `S` and `o`, but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 2):

**C, 78 bytes**

```c
#define f;printf("%.*s\n",i,d));
i;y(char*d){for(;i++<strlen(d)f for(i--;i--f}
```

Comment: [73](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VIc26oCgzryRNQ0lVT6s4Jk9JJ1MnRVPTmivTulIjRbM6Lb9IwzpTW9umuKQoJzUPKJSmABLL1NW1BuK02v@5iZl5GprVlRpK/hkKlamJEEJJ07r2PwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
j+._zt_._z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P0tbL76qJB5I/P/vn6FQmZoIIQA)

```
j          # Join the final array with newlines and print
 +         # Join the two resulting arrays: 
  ._z      #   1. All prefixes of the input (z)
     t     #   2. Remove the first element (full word)
      _    #      of the reverse 
       ._z #      of all prefixes of the input (z)
```

Thanks to ASCII-only for helping get the bytes down!

Comment: [16](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/30c7qSQ@KatSr1TbL7JcSen/f/8MhcrURAgBAA)

Comment: [yours can also be 16](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P6zKNls72y/bOizbNjsgO/v/f/8MhcrURAgBAA)

Comment: [10](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P0tbL76qJB5I/P/vn6FQmZoIIQA)

Comment: @ASCII-only The 16 ones have a trailing empty line, I didn't realize that was allowed so I had had added the `Ik` to fix that. That 10-byte entry is seriously impressive, why not submit it as a seperate answer?

Comment: 1. i don't mind if you post it, 2. don't have time today, 3. it's 90% done by a builtin lol, i don't even know Pyth well

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>79</s> 72 bytes

*Thanks Jo King for helping me save 7 bytes*

I'm a bit late to this golf, but I was bored and didn't see a Python 3 one that gave a printable string and not a list. This isn't exactly very short but this is my first code golf post :)

```
lambda x:'\n'.join(x[:[i,len(x)-i][i>len(x)]]for i in range(1,len(x)*2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCSj0mT10vKz8zT6Mi2io6UycnFcjS1M2Mjc60g7BjY9PyixQyFTLzFIoS89JTNQyhirSMNDX/FxRl5pVopGkoeaTm5OTrKJTnF@WkKCoBZQA)

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! Anonymous lambdas are acceptable submissions, so you can remove the `f=`. You can also change the if statement to a list selection (`[i,len(x)-i][i>len(x)]`) for a total of [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCSj0mT10vKz8zT6Mi2io6UycnFcjS1M2Mjc60g7BjY9PyixQyFTLzFIoS89JTNQyhirSMNDX/FxRl5pVopGkoeaTm5OTrKJTnF@WkKCoBZQA).

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```scala
s=>s.inits.toSeq.reverse++s.inits.drop(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzBCsIwEETv/Yolp4RCwKuQgh8gHnqsHmK71WjdxGQpivjtMRCcw8C8YSaNdrHZn284MuytI8AXI00JdiF8Giha7QLzFnqOji5gOujxOdR0AgM5mS5pR46TZl86HXHFmLBt/3iKPsiNyqFseCE5S3G4whttNaH0414PpTiSUKr55h8)

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>61</s> 57 bytes

```scala
s=>1.to(2*s.size-1).map(x=>s.take(s.size-(s.size-x).abs))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU3BCsIwFLvvKx49tYKFeRQ68APEw47q4W2@6VzXVV@RqvjtdVDNISGBJNyixTQ1V2oDbLF3QDGQOzFsvH8XMOOBFro11OHeuzOYCmq67bM7goHEpip1mORqwZr7Fy1LpUf0MpqKdcCB5C//a1QaG1Yq@XkjWCc7KXYXeBJmEnN/yAdSHJxQqvikLw)

- -4 thanks to [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user)!

Comment: You can use `.abs` directly on `Int` to get [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##NU3BCsIwFLvvKx49tYKFeRQ68APEw47q4W2@6VzXVV@RqvjtdVDNISGBJNyixTQ1V2oDbLF3QDGQOzFsvH8XMOOBFro11OHeuzOYCmq67bM7goHEpip1mORqwZr7Fy1LpUf0MpqKdcCB5C//a1QaG1Yq@XkjWCc7KXYXeBJmEnN/yAdSHJxQqvikLw).

Comment: The 41 byte version is really cool, by the way. Wish I could upvote again.

Comment: Thanks user :) I found it while searching something else. It was pure luck

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
［］─
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNCJXVGRjNEJXUyNTAw,i=SGVsbG8_,v=8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Branch](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/branch-lang/), 32 bytes

```
,[[^]/[./]10.,]^[0^[^]/[./]10.^]
```

Try it on the [online Branch interpreter](https://branch.hyper-neutrino.xyz/#WyIsW1teXS9bLi9dMTAuLF1eWzBeW15dL1suL10xMC5eXSIsIk9oIHllYWggeWVhaCIsIiJd)!

### Explanation

```
,                 Read a character from STDIN
[            ]    While true (while input is not EOF)
 [^]              Keep going up until we hit 0; this is the parent of the first input node
    /             Go to the input node
     [./]         While true, output the node and descend; outputs all input at this point
         10.      Output 10 (newline)
            ,     Read the next character
^                 Go up one space (this puts us on the last input node)
[              ]  While true (while we haven't deleted all of the input yet)
 0^               Zero the current value and go up (delete the last character)
   [^]/           Go to the top again
       [./]       Output all of the input again (gradually gets deleted)
           10.    Output newline
              ^   Go up again; this is the new last input character
```

This can actually be ported quite easily.

## [brainf***](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 56 bytes

```
,[[<]>[.>][-]++++++++++.,]<[[-]<[<]>[.>][-]++++++++++.<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJzraJtYuWs8uNlo3VhsO9HRibaKBIjbYZW1i///3z1CoTE2EEAA)

Basically does the same thing as above. However, BF can't set the value of a cell like Branch can, so instead we can zero with `[-]` (which doesn't actually work well in Branch because `long long int` can take a long long time to zero if its initial value is `-1`) and then to get `10`, we can just do `+` 10 times after zeroing.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 3 bytes

```
¦øm
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%C2%A6%C3%B8m&inputs=It%20took%20me%20a%20long%20time%20to%20make%20this%2C%20plz%20like!&header=&footer=)

-3 thanks to lyxal

```
¦   # Prefixes
 øm # Palindromised
    # Joined by newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 41 bytes

```c
;=aP;=nF;W<=n+1nLaO GaFn;OaW=aSa-LaT1""Oa
```

Nothing too fancy, we just print out the first half, then the middle, then the second.

```php
; = a PROMPT # read stdin
; = n FALSE # will coerce to `0` within the `WHILE` condition, but saves us a space from `=n 0`

# until we're at the length of `a`, print the prefix [0..n] from `a`
; WHILE < (=n + 1 n) (LENGTH a)
    OUTPUT (GET a FALSE n)

# output the entire thing
; OUTPUT a

# continue removing pieces from the end of `a` until it's empty, and printing `a` in the process
WHILE (= a SUBS a (- LENGTH a TRUE) 1 "")
    OUPUT a
```

Comment: You should use `GaF-LaT`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 2 bytes

```
¦∞
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwiwqbiiJ4iLCIiLCJJdCB0b29rIG1lIGEgbG90IG9mIHRpbWUgdG8gbWFrZSB0aGlzLCBwbHMgbGlrZSEiXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 86 bytes

```r
x=utf8ToInt(scan(,''))
for(i in c(y<-1:sum(x|1),rev(y)[-1]))cat(intToUtf8(x[1:i]),"
")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBCoMwEETvfkXIxV1QIbci9gN66qH2JB4kJDVgNxDXErF@u1WEXobh8WbCZq92Is3OE0RcRt1Rlf9JURS4xHWL14ntpfY3YjgUyNIUMbE@gBOOhIa5ylU5Tm@IX4VZMB@YsclVi6g7Bkdc@@d@AbFRpWsxk4nEbU0syN4Mgxfcm2AkHuDBwdHr7PdezKY7Yx/8AA)

I'm learning more and more about better ways to manipulate strings in R, so I'm somewhat proud of this answer. The only part I don't like is the for loop portion, which I feel could definitely be golfed.

Comment: what about `y<-seq(x)`?

Comment: @Droplet you have to be quite careful about `seq(x)`! `seq(x)` behaves like `seq_along(x)` so long as `x` is not an `integer` or `double` of length `1`. In that case, if `x=c(65)`, for example, then `seq(x)` instead returns `1:x`, which would not be the right behavior here. It's rather frustrating!

Comment: You're right, I didn't think of the case when `s` was just one letter

Comment: is the purpose of `x=utf8ToInt(scan(,''))`?

Comment: neat `y<-seq(a=x)` trick that somebody introduced (I forget who) [try it online](https://tio.run/##PYzBCoMwEETvfkXIxV1QwVsp@gE99VB7Eg8hJDUgG4xriYjfbhWhl2F4vJmw29rOpNl5gojrpBVV@Z8URYFr3PZYz2xvjX8Qw6lAlqaIifUBnHAkNCxVPpkRVB0xC@YLC7Z52SFqxeCIG/8@DiC25d11mMlE4r4lFmRvhsEL7k0wEk/w4uDoc/VnLxajrjgGPw) for -2 bytes!

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 76 bytes

```cs
x=>{for(int i=0,s=1;s+i>0;s=i<x.Length?s:-s)WriteLine(x.Substring(0,i+=s));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcy9CsMgEADgvU8hmZT8YNeaM3QPdOjQuRVNbrmAdwVD6LPbIcs3foH7wFjvQXCjkSUjLV4lBbWAP9KWNZIoBNsxXB236K1jwLEMc6RF1olvPZtXRokzUtRleH4/Z6Nthy2wMe5X3SXp5rGqPb5PGuPqHw)

Using an iterative approach, as opposed to LINQ.

I did not realize until after I posted, but my answer is pretty similar to [aloisdg's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180550/8340). Although they are different enough, I might just leave mine too :)

Comment: Gald you posted it. I like it!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>68</s> 63 bytes

```python
i=input()
j=[i[:x]for x in range(1,len(i))]
print j+[i]+j[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxCoAgEADQ3a@4nBRrsFFw7x/EIcjqRE4RI/t6e6987c60joEWqTxNSBatQ2e6P3OFDkhQd7qC0HMKJFBKz0pFahCVQ6@iM2bRfgy@hZQyvLmmY@I/)

-5 thanks to @pppery for spotting an unneeded variable declaration.

Longer than the other Python answers but just another way of doing it.

Comment: [63 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcGxCoAgEADQ3a@4nBRrsFFw7x/EIcjqRE4RI/t6e6987c60joEWqTxNSBatQ2e6P3OFDkhQd7qC0HMKJFBKz0pFahCVQ6@iM2bRfgy@hZQyvLmmY@I/)

Comment: @pppery Thanks for that and well spotted. Leftover from something I had tried earlier!

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 86 bytes

```java
s->{for(int i=0,l=s.length();++i<2*l;)System.out.println(s.substring(0,i<l?i:2*l-i));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU67DoIwFN39ihunVqUxjvJwcHZyNA61Al4sLeHekhjCt2PF6STn3ehBJ83zPRurieCi0cG4AujCw6IBYs0RBo9PaKMmrtyjq2930H1NcrECNLFEBUarquAMo3fq7B2Ftuyzf6CAKp8pKcbK9wIdA@b7nc1J2dLV/BIy3W4xO2xsKq8f4rJVPrDqYpStE6QoPGgpEvsdZvaEx@hNUMp0mtPlQ6W0MWXHYv1fXMsfP62m@Qs)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>122</s> 90 bytes

A worse solution of @xnor's

```python
u=lambda n,s,b:s[:b-abs(n-b)]+'\n'+u(n+1,s,b)if n<2*b else""
def c(w):print(u(0,w,len(w)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBDoIwEEDRvadoumHGlgRxZaMnERcdKJGkzjSWhnD6in/5ftrXt3Bfa3lE/6HJK7bZkstPR62nDNwSvkwzcGMKsLn8Ly6z4nt/JhViDlqfpjCrETZ06bvwCgU6u9kY@CDEOoImEemOJGmst@sP)

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 24 char, 48 bytes

```
{⊃{w[⍵]}¨k,1↓⌽k←⍳¨⍳≢w←⍵}
```

test and how to use it:

```
  h←{⊃{w[⍵]}¨k,1↓⌽k←⍳¨⍳≢w←⍵}
        h ,'1'
1
  h '12'
1 
12
1 
  h '123'
1  
12 
123
12 
1
```

comment: it would build one array of ranges [(1) (1 2) (1 2 3) ecc]
and the code pass each of them to the function {w[⍵]}

Comment: Use `⌷` and a train, and return a vector of vectors to save: `{(⊂¨(+,1↓⌽)⍳¨⍳≢⍵)⌷¨⊂⍵}` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqjUddTYdWaGjrGD5qm/yoZ6/mo97Nh1YAiUedix71btV81LMdyO1qArJrgVoUdNQN1bnSFNQNjaCUsToA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 63 bytes

```
(L=2StringLength@#;Do[Print@StringTake[#,Min[n,L-n]],{n,L-1}])&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/1/Dx9YouKQoMy/dJzUvvSTDQdnaJT86AChQ4gARD0nMTo1W1vHNzIvO0/HRzYuN1akGMQxrYzXV/qdZ2VJoBFeag5J/hkJlaiKEUOICa42OBUl4pObk5KOJJGejCESmFqPw/fKV/gMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 77 bytes

```
: f ( s -- ) dup length [1,b] dup reverse 1 tail append [ head ] with map . ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc29DoIwAMTxnae4MGkiJKzwAMqCg3EiDJUeH7G2tS0anr4SXP7DL7ncIPpgXLzf6uZc4kmnqeD5Xqh7erxEmPbkTuhxA@sYwmrdrAOqpG5K9EZyNGqIJQYc4JFlOEIuFop63OZtcXp0Ozh@6DxRIIhZQVhLLdFiopDo8J33M4scVUwvVMqkGJL0OmGl@GeD@AM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 100 bytes

```
StringJoin[#~Join~Reverse[#][[2;;]]&[Append[Take[#,i],"\n"]~Table~{i,1,Length[#]}&[Characters[#]]]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY0xC8IwFIT/Sk0hUxZdO4mbiEjt9nzDM300QZuW5OEi5q/H6C0fd3B3M4njmcRbKpfog0C5SuV0XHyANv@Qe35xTAwtAuy6DlHDfl05jDDQo8bGo1G3oDAPdH9yfnuzNScOk7ja@Wg4OIpkpY5UX6ULqPPSpP9TakiErONxoxDLFw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), <s>83</s> 76 bytes

```
let s=readline(stdin)
let l=len(s)
for a in 1..l*2-1:echo(s[0..<l-abs(a-l)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBCoAgEAXQfadwqYGSLSP33SFaWE4k/EZwvL/RWz7Ob@@gpiRUigmZSUtLmc3wLwKItZjhLlVFlVl55zDO1i90PUXLPjm3wsZTdLQwh@l9I6B8)

My first time golfing in Nim. All inputs are welcome!

This is a port of my F# and C# answer.

- -7 bytes by using the `[a..<b]` instead of `substr()` ([source](https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/355#18126))

Answer (score 1):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 37 bytes

```
f s{{seq 1,#s-1;seq#s,1}|[s[:_],"
"]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfz/P02huLq6OLVQwVBHuVjX0BrIVC7WMaytiS6OtoqP1VHiUoqt/Z@bmJlXnaYQX/s/uKQoMy@dKz9DoTI1EUIAAA)

Explanation:

```
f s{ /* Function f(s) */
 {
  seq 1,#s-1; /* Push numbers 1..#s-1 to the stream (#s = length of s) */
  seq #s,1    /*   --..--     #s..1    --..-- */
 }|
 [       /* Print the following things for each _ in the stream: */
  s[:_], /*  Substring of s from 0 to _ */
  "
"        /*  Newline */
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 91 bytes

```javascript
a=>{r=[];for(i=0;++i<a.length;)r.push(a.slice(0,i));return[...r,a,...r.reverse()].join`\n`}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcUxDoMwDADAnVewkQhqsafp3B8wUCQiMBBkxcgJLFXfnra33O4uFyfxR7oFnjEvNjv7eIvtB7OwKG9bU9f@7oAwrGkzWuA446YcRPITqrbxWhvBdEroAUAa1/wDwQslotID7OzD@ArjJ08cIhMC8aqK8mdR1ROJuOxYaK50oU3@Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 3 bytes

```
…ṫṣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//1HDsoc7Vz/cufj/f/8MhcrURAgBAA)

As simple as it gets.

```
…	| prefixes
 ṫ	| palindromize
  ṣ	| join with newlines
```

Comment: Bytes? These look like Unicode characters to me.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Gaia, like some other golfing languages, uses a custom code page so that each instruction is a single byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 60 bytes

```sh
for c (${(s::Oa)1})(($#a))&&a=($c $c$^a $c)||a=$c
<<<${(F)a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9Py2/SCFZQUOlWqPYyso/UdOwVlNDQ0U5UVNTTS3RVkMlWUElWSUuEUhq1tQk2qokc9nY2ABVu2km1v6v5UpTUPdIzcnJVyjPL8pJUVT/DwA)

```sh
for c (${(s::Oa)1})          # (s::) splits the first parameter, (Oa) reverses order
    (( $#a )) &&             # if $a is not empty, then
        a=($c $c$^a $c) ||   # ...set a to the current character, then the array with
                             # the current character prepended to each element, else
        a=$c                 # ...set a to the current character
<<< ${(F)a}                  # print a; (F) joins on newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 52 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,i=1:s[i:]and[s[:i]]+f(s,i+1)+[s[:i]]or[s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRoVgn09bQqjg60yo2MS8lujjaKjM2VjtNAyiubaipDRXIL4oujv1fUJSZV6KgHpOnrpeVn5mnkaahHlwCFEtX19T8zwUA)

Returns a list of strings.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>28</s> 29 bytes

```
l_,{_A)<oNo}fA_,{_A)~<oNo}fA;
```

My first CJam answer, so this can probably be golfed quite a lot

Edit: actually made it work correctly, at the cost of a byte

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/PydepzreUdMm3y@/Ns0RwqmD8qz//w8uKcrMSwcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 59 bytes

```
Print/@Table[#~StringDrop~-Abs@i,{i,l=-StringLength@#,-l}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P6AoM69E3yEkMSknNVq5LrgEyE93KcovqNN1TCp2yNSpztTJsdWFiPuk5qWXZDgo6@jm1Maq/U/Td6jmUoJIKelwKXmk5uTkgxj@GQqVqYkQQomr9j8A)

---

Taking input as a list of characters, and returning a list of character lists, **39 bytes**:

```
Table[#~Drop~-Abs@i,{i,l=-Tr[1^#],-l}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PyQxKSc1WrnOpSi/oE7XManYIVOnOlMnx1Y3pCjaME45Vkc3pzZW7X9AUWZeiYODQ5qDc0ZiUWJySWpRsYOymr5DNZdScAlQMl1Jh0vJIzUnJx/E8M9QqExNhBBKXLX/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 254 bytes

```
<>(<()>)<>{({}(<()>))<>{({}<>)<>}{}((()()()()()){})(<()>)<>{({}(<()>))(({}<>)<{({}<>)<>}>{})(<()>)<>{({}<>)<>}{}}{}}<>{({}<>)(<()>)<>{({}<>)<>}{}((()()()()()){})(<()>)<>{({}(<()>))(({}<>)<{({}<>)<>}>{})(<()>)<>{({}<>)<>}{}}{}<>}<>{{}}<>{}{}{({}<>)<>}<>{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rU1JCsMwDPyKjhIkfYHxPc9wS0KNnao0uhm/XZXJBiXHIsFoRjPS/RPiq59ySKrOo0Py5HzBUtd5I66p1URE2otKpYsAbvYz5n@M@7HWh3Jl@Pc3Q9PWr0bPbeOqg4AwJ5hHCJBZgCeQaEwY5pAMn3Hp4J0XyDGNN@0fXw)

Harder than expected (or maybe i'm just not very talented in Brain-Flak ^^)

**Explanation:**

```
<>(<()>)<>              push 0 on second stack

                        ### copy words with increasing letter count to second stack
{                       while letters on stack
  ({}(<()>))            push 0 after first letter
  <>{                   move letters up to next 0 from second to first stack
    ({}<>)<>
  }
  {}                    pop 0
  ((()()()()()){})      append newline
  (<()>)                push new 0
  <>
                        ### append word from first to second stack
  {                     While letters on stack
    ({}(<()>))          push 0 after first letter
    (                   move letter on "third" stack for later use
      ({}<>)            move letter to other stack
      <{                move letters up to next 0 from second to first stack
        ({}<>)<>
      }>
      {}                pop 0
    )                   save letter from "third" stack
    (<()>)              push new 0
    <>{                 move letters up to next 0 from second to first stack
      ({}<>)<>
    }
    {}                  pop 0
  }
  {}                    pop 0
}
<>

                        ### copy words with decreasing letter count to second stack
{                       while letters on second stack
  ({}<>)(<()>)<>        move letter and 0 on first stack
  {                     move letters up to next 0 from second to first stack
    ({}<>)<>
  }
  {}                    pop 0
  ((()()()()()){})      append newline
  (<()>)                push new 0
  <>
                        ### append word from first to second stack
  {                     While letters on stack
    ({}(<()>))          push 0 after first letter
    (                   move letter on "third" stack for later use
      ({}<>)            move letter to other stack
      <{                move letters up to next 0 from second to first stack
        ({}<>)<>
      }>
      {}                pop 0
    )                   save letter from "third" stack
    (<()>)              push new 0
    <>{                 move letters up to next 0 from second to first stack
      ({}<>)<>
    }
    {}                  pop 0
  }
  {}                    pop 0
  <>
}

                        ### Tidy up
<>
{{}}                    delete input
<>
{}{}                    pop 0 and newline
{({}<>)<>}              move everything from second to first stack
<>
{}                      pop newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>107</s> 106 bytes

```java
(s)->{int l=s.length(),i=0;var r=new String[2*l-1];for(;i<l;r[i]=r[2*l-i-2]=s.substring(0,++i));return r;}
```

Loops over the characters of the input string and fills the resulting array from both sides.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY8xb4MwEIVn@BWnTHYBK81qyNitU8eIwSFAjhqD7DNVFPHbqRNgurun956@69Sksu72u2A/DpagC7fwhFo03lSEgxFf2yLjePRXjRVUWjkH3woNPOM4cqQoqLsv/yGLpk3XcSnP0BSwMMez8xMNgS6c0LVp6c54isVRTsqCLUz9B1vk9KGzz1I2g2UScy3tBcvCvmXMTmXIO391by87pkmCnEtbk7cGrJwXuXNuYNOAN@gDLduRQNnW8QAf7YqtnddUNEKNo36ww73WejhwGUcvihc2QkDFfDVuD0hMEh5KHo7qXgyexBjqSBu22gJ3qJjjefkH)

107 -> 106: i=0 at initialisation so removed from for loop

Comment: Nice golf! +1'ed

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 43 bytes

```
0>&ir[sp<l&:rp[o]r(10)o>]<rpr[p&s&o(10)o&l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/9/ATi2zKLq4wCZHzaqoIDo/tkjD0EAz3y7WpqigKLpArVgtHyyglhP7/79/hkJlaiKEAAA)

The logic here is to go through each character (codepoint in Ly) of the input string, add it to a second stack, print the accumulated characters, then go back to the input.  Once the input is exhausted, start with the "whole string" copy and do the reverse (remove a character, print, loop) until it's empty.

```
0>&ir[sp<l&:rp[o]r(10)o>]<rpr[p&s&o(10)o&l]  #
0                                            # Push 0 on the stack
 >                                           # Switch to stack on the right
  &i                                         # Read input onto the stack as codepoints
    r                                        # Reverse the stack
     [                  ]                    # Loop until stack is empty
      s                                      # Stash the current char
       p                                     # Delete it from the stack
        <                                    # Switch to stack on the left
         l                                   # Load the stashed character
          &:                                 # Duplicate stack on itself
            rp                               # Reverse stack, pop the top (0)
              [o]                            # Print stack until we hit a 0
                 r(10)o                      # Reverse the stack, print a LF
                       >                     # Switch to stack on the right
                         <                   # Time to shrink... Switch left
                          rpr                # Remove 0 at front of stack
                             [            ]  # While stack not empty
                              p              # Delete one character
                               &s            # Stash the whole stack
                                 &o          # Print the stack in order
                                   (10)o     # Print a LF
                                        &l   # Restore the stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 96 bytes

```python
def f(s):
    for i in (a:=range(len(s))):print(s[:i+1])
    for i in a[::-1][1:]:print(s[:i+1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyU1TSFNo1jTiksBCNLyixQyFTLzFDQSrWyLEvPSUzVyUvOA0pqaVgVFmXklGsXRVpnahrGaqMoTo62sdA1jow2tYtHU/f8PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>65</strike> 63 bytes

Returns a list of lines.

```python
lambda s:[s[:[i,2*len(s)-i][i>len(s)]]for i in range(len(s)*2)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcgxDoAgDEDRqzRMrVEH3Uz0Ch4AGTCC1mgx4OLpcWD5efnP9x5B@uzHJV/2XjcLadBJD5rrrrqcYKKGjeap2BgfIjCwQLSyOyy76sjkJ7K8qBZR7RlY0KOaD/icLVFElH8)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 64 bytes

Here's another JS solution:

```js
s=>(l=s.length,f=i=>i<l*2?s.slice(0,i>l?l-i:i)+`
`+f(i+1):"")(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 78 bytes

```
func[s][repeat n l: length? s[print copy/part s n]loop l[take/last s print s]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYoxCsMwDAD3vEL4A9mzdO1W6Co0iERuSoUsLHXI692GLMdxXJdtPGVDmuoy6tdWDMIuLpxgoAuo2Cv3GwR6f1vC2vyYnXtCgJG25qCY/JFZOc54bUE0KpS7qLYy/e2xwyF8oYwf)

Answer (score 0):

## x86 machine code (Linux), 53 bytes

```
00000000: 89cf 31d2 4252 e814 0000 005a 803c 1100  ..1.BR.....Z.<..
00000010: 75f2 4a52 e806 0000 005a 09d2 75f4 c36a  u.JR.....Z..u..j
00000020: 015b 6a04 58cd 806a 0ab2 0189 e1b0 04cd  .[j.X..j........
00000030: 805e 89f9 c3                             .^...
```

Assembly:

```bash
section .text
	global func
func:				;Main function with args: char* ecx
					;Clear registers
	mov edi, ecx			;push pointer to original string
	xor edx, edx			;message length, start at 0
	loop_a:				;Increasing length loop:
		inc edx				;increment message length
		push edx			;save message length
		call print_text			;print string with newline
		pop edx				;get message length
		cmp byte [ecx + edx], 0		;If not at end of string:
		jne loop_a			;continue looping
	loop_b:				;Decreasing length loop:
		dec edx				;decrement message length
		push edx			;save message length
		call print_text			;print string with newline
		pop edx				;get message length
		or edx, edx			;If edx != 0:
		jne loop_b			;Continue loop
	ret

print_text:			;Function to print string (pointer in ecx) with newline:
	push 1
	pop ebx				;fd of stdout
	push 4
	pop eax				;syscall #4 (write)
	int 0x80			;run syscall (msg is in ecx)
	push 0xA			;push newline
	mov dl, 1			;set message length to 1
	mov ecx, esp			;set pointer for syscall to top of stack
	mov al, 4			;syscall #4 (write)
	int 0x80			;run syscall
	pop esi				;reset stack pointer
	mov ecx, edi			;get pointer to original string
	ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVXbcts2EH0mvmKjphVlizLtaKatGWcm10kfMv0Ay6MBwRWFhAI4AGgx4@jb3QVIyqbTdiZv0YNI7J69nLMLKed2ey@4g5cv3//9AV7BmdvVZ3zB7Q4yUP6RbLDavLh47El0dxK6wIUmIIqthgnD1qFRIJWD9Zo7Z2TeOFyv43jDrRO8qmYz2DRKxGLLzcksA7bjUsWzOxYMDq2z1zdXdyu2mrx@83Y1mdPLR6wq7V9TdsjYRpvYF5BXadbh5U0mT08pR8g82GYZO7DDZKBkXZMvREaJWSnEmAHxewwacUuUTmqJkOxeXIRonX8uml0NybsR7tVvT9x25P4GDhHOCrylIgUaQ5bSIOHew/Q6Tf68uVseYEpW0ThIcvg9WV74KANJAdOVmj4cAiyk8wW22C5c68i0J1qCnnz/BaZ3tfEqPT8/uzh4fDhuYLJSJycnb746BKEb5S7ptFK/2pWawPPYL0IyO3IJU02wD/qIrWfmIyYBAm1bQEI91U878Y4hyUjme4vCSa1g4WhXWFRWOudVWIkwvcuIPtkn2olgC9C9dFvgprSXEJaElq1lUQC@rZAbMFhKS4tnWbTTt4CFnHuMB9SN3UKtiToacBq0kaVUVNHSbqqSRa02FNDO/ZcP2KG1vESoUJVuOyccNw5IlpRFldb1mnct/qWEQW4pRw8F772kvqQSfbIokx61Q5rDOC/BQmd9Uctv8XuEvy7d2NZerEAnzLTrvdNF4b6SCn1CXR/rlvgvFQVtZe4Hf03iwKkH38wh9WQ2oHRgiaoAvekreDafFULH2@cVWjmpms4U9Au@vNPkHf6XJgU@aFLgT6TJk@mTEPQGz64gHZHPw7I9Js8ig46xh1a8BNmHYWdp1UZ9xcMO0mKT@rNRo1QqMD9nXcN51/CmH0WhG9cjlj2Cdwj71QZBfllCvDfS4YxFvmja/pF6v2kUDJh4Z0uQdmigT5i2r4/X5Cibv0RFNYfzUOM72Ty58/6qCa@drQfgwJJ@o4@FCe2o50CFiy9dIKf0yx@k0HO3MnA36AuGlEPZxz0Vcpj5/91@muE9/e3d/wM)

Comment: Tip: try and merge the increasing and decreasing length loops, like i did in my x64 answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>92</s> 91 bytes

```
s->{for(int i=0,l=s.length();i++<l*2-1;System.out.println(s.substring(0,i<l?i:l-(i-l))));};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxDoIwFEV3vuLFqVXbqKMF3YiLk6NxqNji02cxvEJiCN@OjfEudznnPGxv1eP2nCqyzHC0GIYMQ3Stt5WDcugbvIEXp9hiqIGlGbN3dyWsgKON6X7AK3l/5nwB29YsYchK8FBMrHaDb1qRqoDFakkFa3KhjnchDS4WOc03am1OH47upZsu6nfqRAqCNXdX/lXFaok57XFLSqAimWZGM3ntxezgiJqZNNk4Tl8)
-1 byte by using a for loop instead of a while

Comment: [87 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY6xDoIwFEV3vuLFqRVojKMV3YiLk6NxqNjiw0chvGJiCN@OjXG6y7knpzFvkzeP11KRYYazQT8l6IMdnKkslNO7wwc4cQkD@hpY6jnpxzthBRxMiPMD2vj7M9cbmKFmCVNSgoNi4fwwuW4Q0QpYbDIqWJH1dXgKqdMU97Te6suHg21VNwbVR0sgL1jxeOefU2yyiB1xRynlKGWs0ItTTqxOlqhbSZ3M8/IF "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [SAP ABAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABAP) (Unicode), 143 bytes

```
FORM i USING s.DATA(w) = 2 * strlen( s ).WHILE w > 0.w = w - 1.IF w < strlen( s ).WRITE:/ s(w).ELSE.WRITE:/ s(sy-index).ENDIF.ENDWHILE.ENDFORM.
```

Pretty straightforward subroutine. I'm using ABAP's [substring access](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenoffset_length.htm) `var+offset(length)` and the system variable `sy-index`, which represents the index of the current loop. Other than that it's probably pretty self-explanatory, even though it's ABAP.

---

## SAP ABAP (Non-Unicode), 141 bytes

```
FORM i USING s.DATA(w) = 2 * strlen( s ).WHILE w > 0.w = w - 1.IF w < strlen( s ).WRITE:/ s(w).ELSE.WRITE:/ s(sy(10)).ENDIF.ENDWHILE.ENDFORM.
```

Saving two bytes here by accessing the `index` component of `sy` like a substring, despite it being an integer value. In Unicode systems, characters are obviously multi-byte values, therefore using offsets is not allowed in mixed-type structures like `sy`. However, in a non-Unicode (ASCII-based) system, both digits of a number and characters are represented as one byte each, and offsets are allowed for structures like `sy`.

Conveniently `index` is the first 10-byte component of structure `sy`, so we don't need to use an offset. Otherwise we'd not be able to save *anything* here, as `sy+x(10)` is just as long as `sy-index` - or even longer if the offset was >= 10.

---

Output of both programs is obviously the same, screenshot below.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL query, 119 bytes

```sql
SELECT left(@,n)FROM(SELECT*,number/2+1n,len(@)k,number%2-.5m
FROM spt_values)x
WHERE type='P'and n+m<k
ORDER BY(n-k)*m
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1023581/codegolf-by-t-clausen)**

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 65 bytes

```php
for(;($n=$argn)!=$s.=$n[$i++];$b="$s
$b")$a.="$s
";echo"$a$n
$b";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKw1VPJsVRKL0vM0FW1VivVsVfKiVTK1tWOtVZJslVSKuVSSlDRVEvXAbCXr1OSMfCWVRJU8kLj1//8eqTk5@f/yC0oy8/OK/@u6AQA)

Tests: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY2xCsIwEED3fEUMB22o9AOMwVUnB8faIS2xKZRraNJBxG@PaapIM4R7D@6dNTYcT9ZYQsBr5x2VtCI0vuzmpx67bL/SWQ/D@IOroU@t1i@6WhDyGCetWkPzb0Y5miZOX2kH1NRhjCcpktKtGSm7oJ39YfV3ZCLEUi5yQJlW@E6CKyVgBX1R1AIaycARaBgHVaaZiaXEQAEuXoR/fAmmWzM67XPo@QbdFtUWm4jv8AE)

In a loop creates a word with one letter added to it towards input on each iteration until the word has one letter less than the input.

For example if the input is "Hello" the word in first iteration is "H" and on third iteration is "Hel" and on last iteration is "Hell".

This word is appended to `$a` and prepended to `$b` with a newline. At the end `$a`, input, a newline and `$b` are printed.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>56</s> 52 bytes

```c
i;f(*s,l){for(i=0;write(1,s,++i<l?i:l--);puts(""));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P9M6TUOrWCdHszotv0gj09bAurwosyRVw1CnWEdbO9Mmxz7TKkdXV9O6oLSkWENJSVPTuvZ/bmJmnoZmNVeahlJwSVFmXrqSjpmmNYjrkZqTk6@kYwrh@WcoVKYmQgglHUMjoGjtfwA)

-4 thanks to @ceilingcat

Takes a string and its length as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 27 bytes

```
.1/{0=1$?1$<}%n*.-1%@n+n\+\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X89Qv9rA1lDF3lDFplY1T0tP11DVIU87L0Y75v//4JKizLx0AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 79 bytes

```
character(99)a
read*,a
k=len_trim(a)
print('(a)'),(a(1:k-abs(i-k)),i=0,2*k)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcZBDoMgEAXQPcdw44yBRLvTxLM0HxgsocVm5P60iW/10qlNUd2R7vQeXlCEJkrryjAqiJOFKftb6rNp/hDYfDXXRuO/I1sCLVtx8BdlV5ht3mf7mAobqbH3AT5EScMP)

Fortran. Always good for string manipulation

Answer (score 0):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 37 bytes

```
?1&((⑻|⑩")(⑻|')⑹
,)⑺⑺((⑻|⑩")(⑻|')⑺
,)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///f3lBNQ@PRxN01jyauVNIEs9Q1H03cyaUDJHcBETbZXUDZ//89UisV0ksri3UUSjIyixXKE4sVsjPzUhIVMhKLUhRK8hVyE7NTdRSK8xWS80tzUhQq1RNzchRKC8ryS1IhWhLzistTi@wB)

I decided to try an interesting string shifting approach.

Answer (score 0):

## [.+?](https://github.com/EdgyNerd/DotPlusQuestion/blob/master/README.md), 28 bytes

```
((.+).(\n.+)*)
\2\n\1\n\2
$
```

Thanks to [JoKing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king) for giving the original regex, which I then golfed a bit.

## Explanation

```
((.+).(\n.+)*)  The full pattern
(            )  Makes group 1 the entire match, used in the replacement
 (.+).          Makes group 2 every character on the first line, except for the last character
      (\n.+)*   Makes it match the rest, so it all will get replaced

\2\n\1\n\2      Replacement
\2              Group 2 (first line except last character)
  \n            Newline
    \1          Group 1 (entire match)
      \n        Newline
        \2      Group 2 (first line except last character)

$               This match always fails. Makes the first pair repeat until it doesn't match, which happens when the first line has less than 2 characters.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BbsMgDIbvfgpL21RoOlSy2zTue4eSQzrRBpUSC9imPj3DaxT1gGz/fP5kupVpjm@1@ivNqWC@5R0mB5TmMxoe1ZjOPwc9qEzBF7GxcSMB/AmDi4Ix@dIbo98BfSTDgaKZhAQXsrunj6J@aMuc7OF38sGhp23/sbp44dQOUNexfE3/2YGJYcci/l6EDcnfx0dgbTu90AwTdgY14HIN2z0Zs@cej8mNlzv1ytQTUvKxiLbcDE2wjhJqrUKoTiphYytbCba30er2eniG@ulCmP8A) (The second command line argument is input)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `grouping.extras`, 38 bytes

```factor
[ head-clump dup reverse rest append ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcUxDsIwEATAPq9YpScPgAcgGigQFaI42UsSYZzjfEbk9QaJZuYuwRdrl/PhuN9itKXqnMeBHzcpeNAyEwpflTmwQI3uq9qcHbuu608TVsqfvl0xUeImpPpUxKowvmmFv4tDVJkjbi1IShjaFw)

```
            ! "Hello"
head-clump  ! { "H" "He" "Hel" "Hell" "Hello" }
dup         ! { "H" "He" "Hel" "Hell" "Hello" } { "H" "He" "Hel" "Hell" "Hello" }
reverse     ! { "H" "He" "Hel" "Hell" "Hello" } { "Hello" "Hell" "Hel" "He" "H" }
rest        ! { "H" "He" "Hel" "Hell" "Hello" } { "Hell" "Hel" "He" "H" }
append      ! { "H" "He" "Hel" "Hell" "Hello" "Hell" "Hel" "He" "H" }
```